# How do I get a value of datetime.today() in Python that is "timezone aware"?

Tags: python, datetime, date, timezone

I am trying to subtract one date value from the value of `datetime.datetime.today()` to calculate how long ago something was. But it complains:

```
TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

The return value from `datetime.datetime.today()` doesn't seem to be "timezone aware", while my other date value is. How do I get a return value from `datetime.datetime.today()` that is timezone aware?

The ideal solution would be for it to automatically know the timezone.

Right now, it's giving me the time in local time, which happens to be PST, i.e. UTC - 8 hours. Worst case, is there a way I can manually enter a timezone value into the `datetime` object returned by `datetime.datetime.today()` and set it to UTC-8?

Comment: related: [How do I get the UTC time of “midnight” for a given timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373370/how-do-i-get-the-utc-time-of-midnight-for-a-given-timezone)

Comment: Seems like we can use `datetime.now().astimezone()` since Python 3.6

Comment: Thanks @johnchen902. Your comment has been converted to an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49059780/247696

Comment: @johnchen's answer autotomatically gets the answer in the local time zone.  To get the same answer as far back as Python 3.3: use `from datetime import datetime, timezone; datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()`

Comment: Note that `datetime.date` objects can't have an associated time zone, only `datetime.datetime` objects can. So the question is about `datetime.datetime.today`, and not about `datetime.date.today`, which are different. I've edited the question to make this slightly clearer.

Answer (score 505, accepted):

In the standard library, there is no cross-platform way to create aware timezones without creating your own timezone class. (**Edit:** Python 3.9 introduces [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the standard library which does provide this functionality.)

On Windows, there's `win32timezone.utcnow()`, but that's part of pywin32. I would rather suggest to use the [pytz library](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), which has a constantly updated database of most timezones.

Working with local timezones can be very tricky (see "Further reading" links below), so you may rather want to use UTC throughout your application, especially for arithmetic operations like calculating the difference between two time points.

You can get the current date/time like so:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

Mind that `datetime.today()` and `datetime.now()` return the *local* time, not the UTC time, so applying `.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` to them would not be correct.

Another nice way to do it is:

```
datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

which is a bit shorter and does the same.

---

Further reading/watching why to prefer UTC in many cases:

- [pytz documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/)
- [What Every Developer Should Know About Time](http://web.archive.org/web/20160803154621/http://www.windward.net/blogs/every-developer-know-time/) – development hints for many real-life use cases
- [The Problem with Time & Timezones - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) – funny, eye-opening explanation about the complexity of working with timezones (video)

Comment: How about `datetime.now(pytz.utc)` instead of `datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo = pytz.utc)` ?

Comment: @eumiro: Yes, that works too. I'll add it to the answer. thanks

Comment: I ended up removing timezone awareness in the aware date by doing `d1.replace(tzinfo=None)`, and then using `datetime.utcnow()` to get the current UTC time, and then I was able to subtract the two times correctly. Though, it looks like pytz is pretty easy to use. I will likely move to this in the near future so that I can have more flexibility in my application. Thanks! :)

Comment: @mindthief: Actually, removing timezone awareness doesn't make much sense. Python is able to subtract two aware datetime instances. Removing timezone information might give you wrong results if you're working with multiple different timezones.

Comment: yep I made sure I was using only UTC times :). Though of course, having them as aware is certainly preferable and I'll likely move to this soon. This is just what I did to get it working before I saw your answer.

Comment: `now(utc)` doesn't return today (unless it is midnight in UTC), it returns the current time in UTC. You need also [`.replace(hour=0, minute=0, ...)` to get the beginning of the day (like `datetime.today()`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25421145/4279)

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today) say that `today()` returns the current time, not midnight. If there is a use case where midnight is required, yes, the replacement needs to be done accordingly. Since the original question was about datetime difference, I don't think that midnight is required.

Comment: @AndiDog: My comment implies that I thought (incorrectly) that `datetime.today()` is `combine(date.today(), time())`. `datetime` has both `.now()` and `.today()` methods that (as you've correctly pointed out) return (almost) the same thing. There is no `date.now()` method. `date` and `datetime` objects are not interchangeable. Using a datetime object instead of a `date` object can produce subtle bugs; I don't see any reason for `datetime.today()` to exist if it is a near duplicate of `datetime.now()`.

Comment: Adding to this answer, if you happen to be using django, always use `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()` since it will use UTC automatically if `USE_TZ = True`.

`timezone` is locating at `django.utils.timezone`, documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: @MrE, your edit is nonsense and the result is not *"WRONG"* (sic). It makes perfect sense that if I'm working in Los Angeles time and I add 90 days to a datetime whose time is 10PM, then I get a datetime whose time is 10PM, even if I cross a daylight savings boundary. That's the *entire point* of working in localised time; it's the result that makes sense if, for instance, I'm generating meeting times for a club in Los Angeles. Are there circumstances in which this is undesirable? Certainly. But if I'm doing arithmetic with localised timezones, it's because I *explicitly want* this behaviour.

Comment: @AndiDog If I were you, I'd roll back MrE's edit; as I note in my comment above, I think it makes no sense at all and simply shows precisely the behaviour you'd expect while declaring it *"WRONG"* without explanation. But it's your answer, and you're still active here, so I'll leave the choice to you.

Comment: @MarkAmery maybe it is not 'WRONG' in your use case, adding days. but try adding hours, and usually that's not what you want. So yes it depends on the use case. My edit was to point out the difference between using simple timedelta and passing through UTC. You have both methods here. Use the one that suits you.

Comment: @MarkAmery i edited the answer so it is more clear. I hope that suits you better

Comment: I've replaced the whole block added and redacted over again because 1) it contains invalid Python prompt syntax, 2) non-repeatable input values (now) and 3) you only describe one case of where timezone-aware-vs-UTC matters while there are too many existing sources on the Internet to which we could refer for great explanations of the whole context and more problem cases. Ultimately, OP only asked how to create a timezone-aware datetime object, so a short hint/link is preferred instead of having >60% of the answer dedicated to another problem.

Comment: The "What every developer should know about time" link now redirects to windward's homepage, was the content the same as this one? http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2009/11/what-every-developer-should-know-about-time.html

Comment: @AdamParkin thanks for the heads-up! Since your proposed blog article only partially matches the content, I've replaced it with a web archive link.

Comment: In python3 you can simply use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Comment: In 3.9+, this is moved into the Std Lib See @zimm's answer below!

Comment: Please update this answer to correctly put stdlib zoneinfo first and foremost.

Answer (score 197):

Get the current time, in a specific timezone:

```
import datetime
import pytz
my_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
```

Remember to install [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) first.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/newvem/pytz/blob/f137ff00112a9682bc4e4945067b3b88f158d010/pytz/tzinfo.py#L192-L193).

Comment: you should NOT use localized time except for output. Many things go wrong when using timezone based datetime: a simple timedelta does not take daylight saving into account unless you are in UTC time to begin with. Always use timezone aware based on UTC. convert to local timezone on output when needed.

Comment: To reiterate a disagreement with @MrE that I've previously voiced in the comments on the accepted answer: there are perfectly valid reasons to work with localised datetimes and *"you should NOT use localized time except for output"* is overly broad advice. Suppose you're adding 1 day to a datetime a few hours before a daylight savings boundary at which the clocks go back by an hour. What result do you want? If you think the time should be the same, use localised datetimes. If you think it should be an hour earlier, use UTC or timezone-naive datetimes. Which makes sense is domain-dependent.

Comment: @MarkAmery as much as I can agree that you may want to ADD or SUBTRACT a number of days or hours and not care about timezone issues (like your example), this comment pertains to passing timezone corrected time to a client. Since Python is primarily used for back end processes, it passes times to a client. The server should always pass date/time in UTC and the client should convert it to its own local date/time/timezone, otherwise bad things happen: just check the output of `datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 5, 9, 43, 45, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))` and see if that's what you expected

Comment: *"The server should always pass date/time in UTC and the client should convert it to its own local date/time/timezone"* - no, this isn't universally true. Sometimes using the client's timezone is inappropriate and the appropriate timezone needs to be transmitted as part of the data. If, as a Londoner, I view the meeting times of a San Francisco chess club on their website, I should see them in San Francisco time, not in London time.

Comment: @MrE (As for `datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 5, 9, 43, 45, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))`, yeah, that's a horrible trap of Python's `datetime` API. For anyone wondering WTF is up with the result, the answer is that the `tzinfo` argument to the `datetime` constructor is [just plain broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24856814/1709587) for `pytz` timezones; you need to use the timezones' `.localize()` method to create timezone-aware datetimes instead.)

Comment: "If, as a Londoner, I view the meeting times of a San Francisco chess club on their website, I should see them in San Francisco time, not in London time." Then don't use timezones, UTC or anything, you just need naive date times.

Comment: In 3.9+, this is moved into the Std Lib See @zimm's answer below!

Answer (score 184):

## In Python 3.9+: `zoneinfo` to use the IANA time zone database:

In Python 3.9 or later, you can specify particular time zones using the standard library, using [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> datetime.datetime.now(ZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles"))
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 6, 34, 34, 74823, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/Los_Angeles'))
```

`zoneinfo` gets its database of time zones from the operating system. If the operating system doesn't have an IANA database of time zones, (notably Windows), then the information is retrieved from the first-party PyPI package [`tzdata`](https://pypi.org/project/tzdata/) if available.

## In Python 3.2 or later:

If you need to specify UTC as the time zone, the standard library provides support from this in Python 3.2 or later:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 14, 34, 34, 74823, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

You can also get a datetime that includes the local time offset using [`astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone()
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 15, 34, 34, 74823, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600), 'CET'))
```

In Python 3.6 or later, you can shorten the last line to:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 15, 34, 34, 74823, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600), 'CET'))
```

If you want a solution that uses only the standard library and that works in both Python 2 and Python 3, see [jfs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25421145/247696).

Comment: There's also `datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)))` which can utilize `timedelta` to specify the `tz` parameter to `now()`.

Comment: @Torxed That's fascinating. That would give you a fixed offset time zone. I would prefer to use a time zone linked to a location or political area like `America/Los_Angeles`, as the latter takes into account daylight saving time.

Comment: I guess you could use [.tzname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.tzname) together with [.dst](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.dst) for that and feed it to `tz=`. There's an example of a [custom class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-time) too. But yea, `ZoneInfo` is neat, just thought I'd point people to a builtin that does the same thing *(more or less *in*conveniently)*

Answer (score 48):

A one-liner using only the standard library works starting with Python 3.3. You can get a local timezone aware `datetime` object using [`astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) (as [suggested by johnchen902](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware/49059780#comment77694396_4530069)):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

aware_local_now = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()

print(aware_local_now)
# 2020-03-03 09:51:38.570162+01:00

print(repr(aware_local_now))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 9, 51, 38, 570162, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'CET'))
```

Comment: The documentation is a big help, found here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone . This incredibly basic piece of functionality is buried deep in an obscure paragraph in the docs, so that this stackoverflow answer is effectively the only place on the entire internet with this information. In the documentation, it can also be seen that, since Python 3.6, `datetime.now()` can be called without any arguments and return the correct local result (naive `datetime`s are presumed to be in the local time zone).

Comment: Passing `timezone.utc` to `now` is not needed here, you can just run `datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()`

Comment: @Flimm, it is needed if you want to support Python <3.6.

Comment: **str(datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone())**  ->  
**'2020-09-18 19:19:33.508176+05:30'**  | Is there any way I get the date object with **UTC** timezone? It's always giving the timezone as **IST**. I don't want to use any other python library like **pytz**

Comment: @SauravKumar, that is not the original question. Try `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

Comment: Is there a catch to this? It's bizarre to me that this is hardly mentioned in the official documentation or anywhere else on the internet. "Aware" datetimes are obviously preferred over naive ones, so why isn't this the default way to get the current datetime with Python? If this is possible with the standard library since Python 3.3, why doesn't `datetime.now()` just return an aware object in the local timezone in the first place?

Answer (score 21):

Here's a stdlib solution that works on both Python 2 and 3:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now(utc) # Timezone-aware datetime.utcnow()
today = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, tzinfo=utc) # Midnight
```

where `today` is an aware datetime instance representing the beginning of the day (midnight) in UTC and `utc` is a tzinfo object ([example from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects)):

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta

ZERO = timedelta(0)

class UTC(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO

utc = UTC()
```

Related: performance comparison of [several ways to get midnight (start of a day) for a given UTC time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271060/select-based-on-timestamp-and-update-timestamp-with-zero/33276464#33276464).
Note: it is more complex, to [get midnight for a time zone with a non-fixed UTC offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373370/how-do-i-get-the-utc-time-of-midnight-for-a-given-timezone).

Comment: In 3.9+, this is moved into the Std Lib See @zimm's answer below!

Comment: @Marc: utc timezone is available in stdlib since Python 3.2 and [almost] functional local timezone since Python 3.3. Python 3.9 introduces zoneinfo (many other timezones) into stdlib [that is great] but you don't need it in this case. See [@Flimm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39168818/4279).

Answer (score 20):

Another method to construct time zone aware datetime object representing current time:

```
import datetime
import pytz

pytz.utc.localize( datetime.datetime.utcnow() )
```

You can install [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) from PyPI by running:

```
$ pipenv install pytz
```

Comment: note that `pytz.utc` and `pytz.UTC` are both defined (and are the same)

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted one since it is more universal: `replace()`ing timezone is generally error-prone in most other uses, while `localize()`ing is the preferred way of assigning  timezone to naive timestamps.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: `.localize()` method fails for ambiguous local times (non-utc input). [@philfreo's answer that uses `.now(pytz_timezone)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16660476/4279) continues to work in such cases.

Comment: As specified in python docs, `.now(pytz_timezone)` does exactly the same as `localize(utcnow)` - first it generates current time in UTC, then it assigns it a timezone: "<...>In this case the result is equivalent to `tz.fromutc(datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz))`".  Both answers are correct and work always.

Comment: The only naive (non-utc) time that can be safely made timezone aware is _now_ : the underlying system is supposed to know the UTC value and `pytz` through OLSON db is supposed to know how to convert it to any timezone in the world. Making any other naive (non-utc) time timezone aware is difficult because of the ambiguity during daylight saving shifts. That's not a problem of `.localize` (feeding it a `is_dst` value makes it work for any date). That's an inherent problem of daylight saving practice.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins **wrong.** Ask a separate question if don't understand why `.localize(now)` fails.

Comment: or ask a separate question if you don't understand why `localize` is better than `replace` for non-utc dates.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: use `@..` if you want me to be notified about your comments as I do. What is wrong: 1. `pytz.utc.localize()` is better  than `.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` -- **wrong** 2. `non_utc_tz.localize(utcnow)` is better than `.now(non_utc_tz)` -- **wrong**. Look at your [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware#comment40506068_14796941) and [2nd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware#comment47588748_14796941) comments.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian __wrong__. `localize` doesn't fail for ambiguous timedates (non-utc input) - if you give it correct `is_dst` parameter. Look at your [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware/14796941?noredirect=1#comment47577143_14796941) comment. `pytz.utc.localize(<naive_utc_date>)` does exactly the same as `<naive_utc_date>.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` - this is not my point. If you repeat one and the same incorrect thing million times it wont become more correct just because of that.

Comment: Also, `non_utc_tz.localize(utcnow)` does exactly the same thing as `<naive_utc_date>.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)`. I see no point in arguing about that.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: I'll remind you: the quesiton is "timezone-aware datetime.today()". Fact: `datetime.now(tz)` works without specifying `is_dst` parameter. Fact: `.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` works for UTC timezone. Fact: `tz.localize(now)` may fail for non-utc timezones. You can disambiguate using `is_dst` (for some timezones, it works only in recent versions)  but how do you find out `is_dst` programmatically anyway? Conslusion: `.now(tz)` is a better option than `tz.localize(now, is_dst=is_dst)` here (you could use `.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` for performance reasons if your profiler says so).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I'll remind you: I didn't suggest `non_utc_tz.localize(non_utc_now, is_dst=is_dst)`. That's what you say. Fact: your conclusion doesn't have anything to do with what I said.

Comment: Let me repeat my point: Both `replace` and `localize` can be used for assigning a time zone to a naive timestamp. Both work identically when the operation is unambiguous.
But if the assignment is ambiguous `localize` is better because it will warn you about it through raising an exception which you can catch
and then re-run it with the correct is_dst value if you know it (you can ask an end-user for example) or arbitrary value giving you 50:50 chance of the right guess. 
`Replace` on the other hand will give the same 50:50 chance of the right guess but it wont inform you about the ambiguity.

Comment: Otherwise I agree with all of your Facts. And I also find `datetime.now(pytz.utc)` the best way to do it.

Comment: Plz review my [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29951134/237105) to this question.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: **wrong**. `.replace()` may fail for any timezone that had a different utc offset in the past even if the result is unambiguous. Always use `.localize()` instead of `.replace()` for timezones with a non-fixed utc offset: [Datetime Timezone conversion using pytz](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27531718/4279)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian **at last** you got my my point ("localize()ing is the preferred way of assigning timezone to naive timestamps"). Yeah, I agree, **you have been wrong** from the very beginning. One year is really not so long for such a formidable question ;)

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: **wrong**. Your point: [*".now(pytz_timezone) does exactly the same as localize(utcnow)"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware/14796941?noredirect=1#comment47588748_14796941) is still wrong. Reread my comments carefully this time.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian you can't admit **you've been wrong** all the time? Calm down, reread my comments carefully and stop spamming me.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: you can't provide a single statement from my comments that is wrong. If you continue to post incorrect statements; I might continue to refute them. It looks like it is pointless in your case but I might continue to do it so that  you wouldn't misled other people.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian You seem to like long-term conversations. I'll answer you in a year. Noone will read a conversation this long and this pointless anyway. Didn't I ask you to stop **spamming** me?

Comment: In 3.9+, this is moved into the Std Lib See @zimm's answer below!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **Django**, you can set dates non-tz aware (only [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

**Comment** the following line in settings.py:

```
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: where did you see django mentioned in this question?

Comment: Some kind soul deleted my previous comment-apology here, so again: shame on me, wrong answer as the question is not Django-specific. I left it because it might help some users anyway but I will delete it when the score approaches 0. If this answer is inappropriate, feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 10):

Use dateutil as described in *[Python datetime.datetime.now() that is timezone aware](http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=802)*:

```
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
# Get the current date/time with the timezone.
now = datetime.datetime.now(tzlocal())
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218506/how-to-get-system-timezone-setting-and-pass-it-to-pytz-timezone) by J.F. Sebastian for a situation where this gives incorrect result.

Comment: I think the error in the other post is only relevant in specific use cases. The `tzlocal()` function still is one of the simplest solutions and should definitely be mentioned here.

Comment: In 3.9+, this is moved into the Std Lib See @zimm's answer below!

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way to generate it with the stdlib:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

FORMAT='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
date=datetime.strptime(time.strftime(FORMAT, time.localtime()),FORMAT)
```

*date* will store the local date and the **offset from UTC**, not the date at UTC timezone, so you can use this solution if you need to identify **which timezone the date is generated at**. In this example and in my local timezone:

```
date
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 1, 12, 15, 44, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)))

date.tzname()
'UTC+02:00'
```

The key is adding the `%z` directive to the representation FORMAT, to indicate the UTC offset of the generated time struct. Other representation formats can be consulted in the datetime module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

If you need the date at the UTC timezone, you can replace *time.localtime()* with *time.gmtime()*

```
date=datetime.strptime(time.strftime(FORMAT, time.gmtime()),FORMAT)

date    
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 1, 10, 23, 51, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

date.tzname()
'UTC'
```

**Edit**

**This works only on python3**. The z directive is not available on python 2 [_strptime.py code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/_strptime.py#L194)

Comment: ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

Comment: You are on python 2, right? Unfortunately, It seems the z directive is not available on python 2.  [_strptime.py code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/_strptime.py#L194)

Answer (score 9):

It should be emphasized that since Python 3.6, you only need the standard lib to get a timezone aware datetime object that represents local time (the setting of your OS). Using [astimezone()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone)

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 25, 10, 59).astimezone()
# e.g.
# datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 25, 10, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600), 'Mitteleuropäische Zeit'))

datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 25, 12, 59).astimezone().isoformat()
# e.g.
# '2010-12-25T12:59:00+01:00'

# I'm on CET/CEST
```

(see @johnchen902's comment).

Note there's a small caveat though, don't expect any "DST-awareness" from a timedelta timezone.

Answer (score 5):

[pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) is a Python library that allows accurate and cross platform timezone calculations using Python 2.3 or higher.

With the stdlib, this is not possible.

See a similar question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/python-cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes).

Comment: In 3.9+, this is moved into the Std Lib See @zimm's answer below!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using a readable timezone and that works with today():

```
from pytz import timezone

datetime.now(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
datetime.now(timezone('Europe/Berlin')).today()
```

You can list all timezones as follows:

```
import pytz

pytz.all_timezones
pytz.common_timezones # or
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting a timezone-aware date in `utc` timezone is enough for date subtraction to work.

But if you want a timezone-aware date in your current time zone, `tzlocal` is the way to go:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone  # pip install tzlocal
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now(get_localzone())
```

PS `dateutil` has a similar function (`dateutil.tz.tzlocal`). But inspite of sharing the name it has a completely different code base, which as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218506/how-to-get-system-timezone-setting-and-pass-it-to-pytz-timezone) by J.F. Sebastian can give wrong results.

Comment: python is usually used on the server. Local time zone on a server is usually pointless and should always be set to UTC. Setting datetime tzinfo this way fails in some cases. better use UTC, then localize to the wanted timezone only on output.
any timedelta computation for example doesn't consider daylight saving, so these should be done in UTC, then localized.

Comment: @MrE Wrong, offtopic, examples?

Comment: try using a datetime object localized in a timezone that observes daylight saving, add a number of days to change daylight saving state, and you'll see that operating on datetime objects in localized timezone fails and won't respect daylight saving. Hence my comment that you should ALWAYS do any datetime operation in UTC time.

Comment: the point being: don't do this, do your operations in UTC, and then use datetime.astimezone(timezone) to convert to the localtime zone on output.

Comment: In 3.9+, this is moved into the Std Lib See @zimm's answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, in my mind a better one, is using `Pendulum` instead of `pytz`. Consider the following simple code:

```
>>> import pendulum

>>> dt = pendulum.now().to_iso8601_string()
>>> print (dt)
2018-03-27T13:59:49+03:00
>>>
```

To install Pendulum and see their documentation, go [here](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#installation). It have tons of options (like simple ISO8601, RFC3339 and many others format support), better performance and tend to yield simpler code.

Comment: not sure why the vote down here, this code is working in multiple programs that run 7/24 for me :). not that i mind other opinion, but please say why it is not working for you, to allow me to check it. Thanks in advance

Comment: this is a great suggestion, in this messy field like date time manipulation readability and ease of use comes first, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Especially for non-UTC timezones:

The only timezone that has its own method is `timezone.utc`, but you can fudge a timezone with any UTC offset if you need to by using `timedelta` & `timezone`, and forcing it using `.replace`.

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

In [2]: def force_timezone(dt, utc_offset=0):
   ...:     return dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=utc_offset)))
   ...:

In [3]: dt = datetime(2011,8,15,8,15,12,0)

In [4]: str(dt)
Out[4]: '2011-08-15 08:15:12'

In [5]: str(force_timezone(dt, -8))
Out[5]: '2011-08-15 08:15:12-08:00'
```

Using `timezone(timedelta(hours=n))` as the time zone is the real silver bullet here, and it has lots of other useful applications.

Answer (score 0):

Tyler from 'howchoo' made a really great article that helped me get a better idea of the Datetime Objects, link below

## [Working with Datetime](https://howchoo.com/g/ywi5m2vkodk/working-with-datetime-objects-and-timezones-in-python)

essentially, I just added the following to the end of both my datetime objects

```
.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

Example:

```
import pytz
import datetime from datetime

date = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you get current time and date in python then import date and time,pytz package in python after you will get current date and time like as..

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import time
str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(pytz.utc),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%t"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the timezone as shown below for a timezone-aware date time. The default is UTC:

```
from django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.now()
```

Comment: This only applies to Django apps.

Answer (score -1):

try [pnp_datetime](https://github.com/pypnp/pnp_datetime/blob/master/ExampleAndUsage.md), all the time been used and returned is with timezone, and will not cause any offset-naive and offset-aware issues.

```
>>> from pnp_datetime.pnp_datetime import Pnp_Datetime
>>>
>>> Pnp_Datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 5, 12, 26, 18, 958779, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```