# How to get UTC time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I get the UTC time, i.e. milliseconds since [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) on Jan 1, 1970?

Comment: related: [Python: How to get a value of datetime.today() that is “timezone aware”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4530069/4279)

Answer (score 341):

For Python 2 code, use [`datetime.utcnow()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcnow()
```

For Python 3, use [`datetime.now(timezone.utc)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-datetime) (the 2.x solution [will *technically* work](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow), but has a giant warning in the 3.x docs):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

For your purposes when you need to calculate an amount of time spent between two dates all that you need is to subtract end and start dates. The results of such subtraction is a [`timedelta` object.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

From the python docs:

```
class datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
```

And this means that by default you can get any of the fields mentioned in it's definition -
days, seconds, microseconds, milliseconds, minutes, hours, weeks. Also timedelta instance has total_seconds() method that:

> Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration.
> Equivalent to (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) *
> 10**6) / 10**6 computed with true division enabled.

Comment: possibly nasty surprise about datetime.utcnow() is that is does not return a timezone-aware object despite the name. This is in my opinion a big problem, which is why I prefer my answer below. 
See  "datetime objects with no timezone should be considered as a "bug" in the application."  https://julien.danjou.info/python-and-timezones/

Comment: The concept of a so called naive datetime object (i.e., no timezone information is set) does serve a purpose: I want my alarm clock to ring at 06:00:00 every day no matter where in the world I am. Also it allows for "virtual clocks" in say computer games: It is now 5 pm in my fantasy world. Forcing a timezone onto the datetime object would be awkward, especially with timedelta arithmetics.

Answer (score 206):

**Timezone-aware** `datetime` object, *unlike* `datetime.utcnow()`:

```
from datetime import datetime,timezone
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

---

Timestamp in milliseconds since Unix epoch:

```
datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000
```

Comment: According to the Python 3 documentation this is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: Clean and easy! Should be the preferred way.

Comment: @Marry35 yes, this should be the preferred way NOW.  When the question was first asked `timezone.utc` did not exist.

Comment: And if you prefer to have the local time (e.g. for easier display to user) but still be timezone-safe, you can use `datetime.now().astimezone()`

Answer (score 51):

In the form closest to your original:

```
import datetime

def UtcNow():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    return now
```

If you need to know the number of seconds from 1970-01-01 rather than a native Python `datetime`, use this instead:

```
return (now - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Python has naming conventions that are at odds with what you might be used to in Javascript, see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names). Also, a function that simply returns the result of another function is rather silly; if it's just a matter of making it more accessible, you can create another name for a function by simply assigning it. The first example above could be replaced with:

```
utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow
```

---

All of the above is now considered obsolete.  Python 3.2 introduced [`datetime.timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.2.html#datetime-and-time) so that a proper `tzinfo` for UTC could be available to all.  So the modern version becomes:

```
def utc_now():
   return datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian true, but see the comment I made earlier - this is the form closest to the code in the question. No need to confuse people by introducing tangents to their question, unless it's relevant.

Comment: There is no reason to promote bad practice without an explicit disclaimer in the answer. I've upvoted your answer but it deserves a comment that shows how it is done idiomatically in Python. Though my comment doesn't follow pep-8 naming convention, to preserve the link with the name used in the question.

Comment: `(now - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()` ... What about just `time.time()`?

Comment: To get the timestamp you either use: 
- time.time() - cast to into to remove miliseconds simply.
- int(datetime.datetime.nowutc("%s")) - returns a string, so thats why I cast to int

Comment: datetime.datetime.utcnow() does not return a timezone-aware datetime, which is really not a good idea,  it's just a question of time before one eventually discovers how horrible that is.

Comment: @TimRichardson I don't disagree, but at the time this answer was written there was no alternative - Python didn't include any `tzinfo` objects, even for UTC.

Comment: `ruff check src`: DTZ003 The use of `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` is not allowed, use `datetime.datetime.now(tz=)` instead. https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/rules/#flake8-datetimez-dtz

Answer (score 21):

```
import datetime
import pytz

# datetime object with timezone awareness:
datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)

# seconds from epoch:
datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc).timestamp() 

# ms from epoch:
int(datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc).timestamp() * 1000)
```

Comment: pytz is deprecated now that the zoneinfo DB/package has been moved into the Std Lib.

Comment: @Marc pytz is not deprecated.

Answer (score 17):

### Timezone aware with zero external dependencies:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def utc_now():
    return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Comment: inorder to print it in zulu format, this is the way to go ```datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')```

Comment: How is it different from `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`?
Just curious. cause I believe the result is exactly the same.

Comment: @GaganDeepSingh Both give the exact same `datetime` object. (There are sometimes multiple paths to the same destination.) `.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)` merely sets the `.tzinfo` member which is unfortunately `None` by default.

Comment: `datetime.utcnow()` is deprecated in Python 3.12, use another answer instead.

Answer (score 10):

From datetime.datetime you already can export to timestamps with method strftime. Following your function example:

```
import datetime
def UtcNow():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    return int(now.strftime("%s"))
```

If you want microseconds, you need to change the export string and cast to float like: `return float(now.strftime("%s.%f"))`

Comment: What's the point of converting to a string and then back to a number when you can get the number directly?

Comment: The point is that you may want to change things on the function and for that reason is better stick to datetime object, not using `time.time()`, 
You could also use time.mktime(now.timetuple()) to convert directly to int.
Anyway, for this simple case `time.time()` is also a valid option.
What I find odd, is going by timedelta to find the seconds.

Comment: Note, that `strftime("%s")` is platform dependent and does not work on Windows. (At least it doesn't for me on Windows 10).

Answer (score 7):

you could use `datetime` library to get UTC time even local time.

```
import datetime

utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() 
print(utc_time.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S'))
```

Comment: What does this 2021 answer add to the conversation? It's the same method as shown in the accepted answer from almost 10 years earlier.

Answer (score 5):

why all reply based on datetime and not time?
i think is the easy way !

```
import time
nowgmt = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
print(nowgmt)
```

Comment: nowgmt will be a string, which is less flexible than having a datetime object

Answer (score 1):

as **datetime.datetime.utcnow()** is deprecated, you can alternatively use below code to get time in UTC

```
datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```