# highcharts datetime axis, how to comput correct timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, highcharts, timezone

Let say I want to draw a series where the first point represents the time 11:30 of november 5 2013. I want the time 11:30 to be the same if I look my chart with a browser in a different timezone. Hence I want useUTC=true. Now, how do I compute the value (milliseconds) to give to highcharts?

I tried with this python code:

```
>>> import datetime,time
>>> t=datetime.datetime(2013,11,5,11,30,00)
>>> time.mktime(t.timetuple())*1000
1383647400000.0
```

But if I plug the value 1383647400000.0 in highcharts I obtain a point with time 10:30 instead of 11:30.

Here is a the code reproducing the malfunctioning: http://jsfiddle.net/2BffA/6/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, but for me 1383647400000 is 10.30 in UTC, so it's displayed  correctly? On a server side create UTC time. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940280/utc-time-in-python

Comment: So, the point is maybe in the python code.... Is time.mktime dependent on the localtime?

Comment: Yet, `time.mktime()` makes from local time, see another answer from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956886/python-calendar-timegm-vs-time-mktime).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in the python code... The correct way to construct a UTC timestamp for 11:30 november 5, 2013 is

```
>>> import datetime, calendar
>>> t=datetime.datetime(2013,11,5,11,30,00)
>>> calendar.timegm(t.utctimetuple())*1000.0 + t.microsecond * 0.0011383651000000.0
1383651000000.0
```

which is the correct timestamp to send to highcharts if useUTC=true

Comment: Your code is malformed and does not execute. What is `0.0011383651000000.0\n1383651000000.0` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Cerin The code shown is the interactive shell. Last line is the result of previous command.

Comment: or use python3.8 dt.timestamp() * 1000