# How do I retrieve UTC time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

What would be the equivalent of `time.ctime()` for UTC time?

Currently, if I enter `time.ctime()` in the interpreter, I get this:

```
'Mon Feb  5 17:24:48 2018'
```

This returns the local time and I would like to know how to get time in the same format except in UTC.

Edit: It's `time.asctime(time.gmtime())`

Comment: possibly duplicate of [How to get UTC time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940280/how-to-get-utc-time-in-python)

Comment: This: `time.asctime(time.gmtime())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

Comment: @khelwood that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @astro No problem. I've posted it as an answer, below.

Answer (score 4):

[`time.gmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime)
returns an object representing the utctime.

To get it into the same format as `time.ctime`, you can use [`time.asctime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.asctime).

```
>>> time.asctime(time.gmtime())
'Mon Feb  5 12:03:39 2018'
```

Comment: looks better one

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import datetime

utc = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
# datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 5, 12, 2, 56, 678723)

str(utc)
# '2018-02-05 12:05:10.617973'
```

Comment: pandas might be a bit overkill here. You can just use `str(utc)` to get a string

Comment: @Farhan.K, noted / updated. Only used `pandas` because it formats nicely without losing structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

> > > 2018-02-05 12:05:53.329809

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code where you can select any timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
utc_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```