# Python - simplest and most coherent way to get timezone-aware current time in UTC?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

`datetime.now()` doesn't appear to have timezone info attached.  I want the current time in UTC.  What do I do?

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> y = datetime.now()
>>> y
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 11, 11, 18, 33, 598489)
```

At first I thought `datetime.utcnow()` was the obvious solution, but then I discovered that it doesn't have timezone info attached either (WTF?).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> y = datetime.utcnow()
>>> y
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 11, 16, 19, 40, 238810)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

Then use the following bit of code

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo = pytz.utc)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3:

```python
datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

In Python 2.x there is no timezone object, but you can write your own:

```python
try:
    from datetime import timezone
except ImportError:
    from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta

    class timezone(tzinfo):
        def __init__(self, utcoffset, name=None):
            self._utcoffset = utcoffset
            self._name = name

        def utcoffset(self, dt):
            return self._utcoffset

        def tzname(self, dt):
            return self._name

        def dst(self, dt):
            return timedelta(0)

    timezone.utc = timezone(timedelta(0), 'UTC')
```

Then you can do `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` just like in Python 3.

Comment: great idea with the python2 polifill!

Answer (score 1):

Use `datetime.utcnow()` for the current time in UTC.

Adapting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware) answer, here is how to make the object timezone-aware.

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 11, 15, 34, 52, 229959, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: That does not attach a UTC timezone to the datetime object unfortunately, since Python doesn't include *any* timezone objects.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ah, yes. I have edited the answer to include time-zone aware solution.