# fractions of seconds and pytz: do you have a cleaner solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytz

I have times in a log that look like this:

1440498131.372625

What I've done using pytz is

```
utc = pytz.utc
for anra in raFromMCCS:
    fsecs = float(anra.time)
    isecs = int(fsecs)
    isec2 = int(fsecs * 1000)
    dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(isecs).replace(tzinfo=utc)
    #print (dt.year)
    dt2 = utc.localize(datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, int((fsecs - isecs) * 1000000)))
    #      dt3 = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(isec2)
    print(dt, dt2)#, dt3)
```

I left in the stupid dt3 attempt to show I'm new to all sorts of things here.

I know that dt2 gives me what I want but it seems like a roundabout way to get there.  If you have a nicer solution, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the float to `fromtimestamp()` directly:

```
d = datetime.fromtimestamp(1440498131.372625, utc)
```

If you know that the input is POSIX time (non-"right" timezone) then you could use the direct formula:

```
d = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=utc) + timedelta(seconds=1440498131.372625)
```

It should provide a portable (wider) range for input timestamps. The rounding behavior should be more consistent between Python versions, see [datetime.utcfromtimestamp rounds results incorrectly](http://bugs.python.org/issue23517).

If input is a string; you could parse microseconds using `strptime('%f')`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

seconds, dot, us = "1440498131.372625".partition('.')
d = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=int(seconds))
if dot:
    d = d.replace(microsecond=datetime.strptime(us, '%f').microsecond)
```

where [`timezone.utc` is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22330133/4279). It also works if microseconds are represented using less than 6 digits e.g., `".372"`.

Only the last code example guarantees to preserve microseconds for any input timestamp.

Comment: Thank you. The first one worked, or at least it gave me the same results (diffed the output) as the first way I was doing it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, another comment for future ref: python3.4  and also, I ended up using     return datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=utc) + timedelta(seconds=float(timeInSecs)) since the ref you provided stated this is the desired behavior of the other way... Once again, diff showed same results as the original way I did it, so I'm sticking with this one.

Comment: @evernoob: to understand why you should use integers instead of floats in the general case, consider `int((datetime.max - datetime.min) / timedelta(microseconds=1))` vs. `(datetime.max - datetime.min) // timedelta(microseconds=1)` (the former is imprecise). Though for the range of everyday timestamps floats should have enough precision.