# Representing Date as numeric number

Tags: python, date, numbers

so I'm trying to figure out a way to convert a normal date in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" (for example : 31/12/2016).

I want to find a way to convert this date into a unique number, so I can re-convert it back.

for example i thought of `sum=day+month*12 + year*365` as the number and then :

```
(sum % 365 ) / 12...
```

but it's not working for each statment. so any ideas?

Comment: Store year, day and month as string, concat it, convert it to int and when you want to reconvert it just go the same way backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It is far better not to handle the strings yourself. Instead use the module called datetime. Here is an incredibly good answer which should hopefully satisfy what you need to do. [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

For example, in your case you would need the following

```
import datetime
your_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("31/12/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then this article [How to convert datetime to integer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154066/how-to-convert-datetime-to-integer-in-python) explains how you can turn it into an integer, but as stated in the answer, this is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***datetime*** module to extract the day, month, and year and then use as you want.

```
In [9]: (y, m, d) = str(datetime.date.today()).split('-')[:3]

In [10]: y, m, d
Out[10]: ('2016', '11', '10')
```

The output is in string format, which can be converted to integers.

```
In [11]: int(y), int(m), int(d)
Out[11]: (2016, 11, 10)
```