# how to convert datetime to numeric format in Python

Tags: python

I have following datetime in Python and want to convert it to numeric

```
 2020-04-01  12:30:01
```

When I convert this to number in excel it returns `43922.5208449074`. How to get the same number in Python?

I tried with following

```
datetime.fromisoformat('2020-04-01 12:30:01').timestamp()
```

But it does not return me the same number. How can we do it in Python

Comment: This question asked many times in stackoverflow. Didn't you try that all?

Comment: Maybe that helps you, was asked before:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154066/how-to-convert-datetime-to-integer-in-python)

Comment: That is the "OLE automation date format". Mention that. So people would not get confused and you will get proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding your problem,
you can use it

```
# Importing datetime.
from datetime import datetime
# Creating a datetime object so we can test.
a = datetime.now()

# Converting a to string in the desired format (YYYYMMDD) using strftime
# and then to int.
a = int(a.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
print (a)
```