# Difference of start date and end date

Tags: python, date

I am trying to get a code to return **true** if the start date is **before or the same** as the end date. However, I am unable to get the correct output for some testing cases.

```
def difference(start_day, start_mon, start_year, end_day, end_mon, end_year):    
    start_date = (start_day, start_mon, start_year)
    end_date = (end_day, end_mon, end_year)
    if start_date <= end_date:
        return True
    else:
        return False

***My output:***
difference(19, 3, 2014, 19, 3, 2014)    #True       
difference(18, 3, 2014, 19, 3, 2014)    #True   
difference(20, 3, 2014, 19, 3, 2014)    #False      
difference(19, 3, 2015, 19, 3, 2014)    #False      
difference(19, 6, 2014, 19, 3, 2014)    #False      
difference(18, 12, 2014, 19, 11, 2014)  #True   <- This is the wrong output
difference(18, 12, 2014, 19, 11, 2015)  #True

***Expected output:***
difference(19, 3, 2014, 19, 3, 2014)    #True       
difference(18, 3, 2014, 19, 3, 2014)    #True   
difference(20, 3, 2014, 19, 3, 2014)    #False      
difference(19, 3, 2015, 19, 3, 2014)    #False      
difference(19, 6, 2014, 19, 3, 2014)    #False      
difference(18, 12, 2014, 19, 11, 2014)  #False      
difference(18, 12, 2014, 19, 11, 2015)  #True
```

I tried different ways of writing the code but I am still unable to obtain the expected output for all the test cases.

Comment: refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) to find more about python date objects , you can also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154066/how-to-convert-datetime-to-integer-in-python) if you dont want to use any library

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/how-does-tuple-comparison-work-in-python)

> Tuples are compared position by position: the first item of the first
> tuple is compared to the first item of the second tuple; if they are
> not equal (i.e. the first is greater or smaller than the second) then
> that's the result of the comparison, else the second item is
> considered, then the third and so on.

That's how all sequences are compared. [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)

> Sequence objects typically may be compared to other objects with the
> same sequence type. The comparison uses lexicographical ordering:
> first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this
> determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next
> two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

What you want to do instead is compare date objects.

```
from datetime import date


def difference(start_day, start_mon, start_year, end_day, end_mon, end_year):
    start_date = date(day=start_day, month=start_mon, year=start_year)
    end_date = date(day=end_day, month=end_mon, year=end_year)
    return start_date <= end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely want to use tuples you could change the position of year and day in the tuples:

```
def difference(start_day, start_mon, start_year, end_day, end_mon, end_year):    
    start_date = (start_year, start_mon, start_day)
    end_date = (end_year, end_mon, end_day)
    return start_date <= end_date
```