# Subtracting datetime.datetime.now() from a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string that I've converted to a datetime object using parse.

```
time = 'Tue, 30 Sep 2014 16:19:08 -0700 (PDT)'
date_object = parse(time)
```

I want to find the time that has elapsed since then. I tried using `datetime.datetime.now()` and subtract the two, but they are different format and was throwing an error.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: related: [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the *[timezone aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware)* datetime object and substract `date_object` from it:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> time = 'Tue, 30 Sep 2014 16:19:08 -0700 (PDT)'
>>> date_object = parse(time)
>>>
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
>>> now - date_object
datetime.timedelta(550, 84210, 337036)
```

Comment: note: you could pass any timezone to `.now()` e.g., `now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)` -- it does not change the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a timezone-aware datetime object then you could convert it to UTC, to find the elapsed time easily:

```
from datetime import datetime

# <utc time> = <local time> - <utc offset>
then_utc = date_object.replace(tzinfo=None) - date_object.utcoffset()
now = datetime.utcnow()
elapsed = now - then_utc
```

[The explanation of why you should not use `datetime.now()` to get the elapsed time see in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279).

---

You could parse the time string and get the elapsed time using only stdlib:

```
>>> time_string = 'Tue, 30 Sep 2014 16:19:08 -0700 (PDT)'
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
>>> then = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(time_string))
>>> import time
>>> now = time.time()
>>> elapsed_seconds = now - then
```