# Can Dates be Timezone-Aware in Python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, timezone, pytz

There's lots of SO answers on ensuring datetimes are a particular timezone. For example you can ensure your datetime is UTC with

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

now_utc = datetime.utcnow()
```

which yields:

> datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 11, 17, 37, 5, 602054)

you can make that datetime aware of its timezone (e.g. for asserting two different datetime objects are from the same timezone) with

```
now_utc_aware = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

> datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 11, 17, 38, 2, 757587, tzinfo=< UTC>)

But when I pull the date from a timezone-aware datetime, I seem to lose the timezone-awareness.

```
now_utc_aware.date()
```

> datetime.date(2017, 5, 11)

Interestingly, [there's a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware?rq=1) which seems to ask exactly this, and about a date specifically (`datetime.today()`), but the answers (including an accepted one) relate to datetimes. The code I've seen to add timezone awareness to datetimes all seem to throw errors on my `datetime.date` object.

Is it possible to add timezone awareness to a date object?

Comment: Why, and more importantly, how?  The fundamental aspect of a timezone is the time offset.  The date only plays a secondary role in changing how the time is adjusted throughout the year. If you added the awareness to just a date, what would it look like?  What operations would make sense?

Comment: I imagine a case where you have events logged with a `datetime.today()` across different pieces of software, logging info in different tables. Someone joining tables on date might want to confirm that the `date`s all refer to the same dates, i.e. `.today()`s logged using the same timezone as opposed to disparate local timezones.

Comment: I agree with your question though that the notion of time-awareness is much less straightforward for dates than datetimes. Maybe it is meaningless. Hence my question of "can dates be time-aware" not "how do I make dates time-aware?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#available-types):

> *class* datetime.**date**
>   An idealized naive date, ... Attributes: year, month, and day.

There's nothing there for time or time zone.  It's just a date.

While it is true that not everywhere on Earth is on the same date simultaneously (because of time zones), that doesn't mean a date itself has time zone awareness.

As a real-world analogy, think of a date as just a square on a calendar.  One cannot start talking about timezones without introducing time, which is measured by a clock, not a calendar.