# get UTC time for a given time string and timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, pytz

I need to convert a time given by the user (as a string) to UTC depending on the timezone the user is in. So all I need is the offset of the timezone (considering daylight saving time) to UTC. The problem seems to be, that there is no builtin timezone info in python, so I need to require pytz (which I'd rather not). Is there an easier way?

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

TIME_FORMAT = '%H:%M:%S'
TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'


def utctime_for_timestring(timestring, tz=TIMEZONE, tfmt=TIME_FORMAT):
    t = datetime.strptime(timestring, tfmt)
    offset = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(tz)).utcoffset()
    return (t - offset).time()


#  >>> utctime_for_timestring('20:00:00')
# datetime.time(18, 0)
```

Comment: pytz is your friend

Comment: @Will I don't like friends. (I'd rather not introduce a dependency)

Comment: To handle timezone conversions properly, you cannot rely on python's builtin datetime module https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware