# I use APScheduler, many jobs need start right now. I configured next_run_time but it didn't work?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I want my jobs start right now, I know I can use job.modify method to change next_run_time, but many jobs should edit, so I configured the scheduler:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pytz
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(next_run_time=datetime.now)

scheduler.configure(timezone=pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))


def test():
    print('hello', datetime.now())


job = scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=30, id='my_job_id')

print(datetime.now())
scheduler.start()
```

The job doesn't run right now, what shoud I do?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the current time to `scheduler.add_job()`:

```
scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=30, id='my_job_id',
                  next_run_time=datetime.now())
```

Comment: Louie is using the pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai') timezone, so next_run_time should be in this timezone as well: next_run_timezone=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))

Answer (score 0):

You are using a timezone when configuring the scheduler: `scheduler.configure(timezone=pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai'))`

but you are not using timezone when specifying the next_run_time:
`BackgroundScheduler(next_run_time=datetime.now)`

Please use timezone in both places. By the way I would use next_run_time on the job, like Alex has suggested, his answer with the timezone would be:

```
scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=30, id='my_job_id',
              next_run_time=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')))
```

---

I have also fallen into this timezone problem, because I have used APScheduler code from documentation (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html) where they set the timezone to pytz.utc:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=job_stores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=pytz.utc)
```

(notice **`timezone=pytz.utc`** in the end of the line above)

This is why for me `datetime.now()` did not work and I had to use **`datetime.now(pytz.utc)`**

I had to use either `datetime.utcnow()` or better `datetime.now(pytz.utc)` (according to [How do I get a value of datetime.today() in Python that is "timezone aware"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-in-python-that-is-timezone-aware))

So now my full code looks like:

```
scheduler.add_job(my_function, trigger="interval", hours=6, args=[my_argument], id="my_id", next_run_time=datetime.now(pytz.utc))
```

(notice `datetime.now(pytz.utc)` in the end of the line above)