# Difference between pandas datetime and datetime datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, gmt

Hi have some dates in datetime.datetime format that I use to filter a panda dataframe with panda timestamp. I just tried the following and get a 2 hour offset :

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(datetime(2020, 5, 11, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()*1e9)
```

The output is:

```
->Timestamp('2020-05-10 22:00:00')
```

Can anybody explain why this gives a 2 hour offset? I am in Denmark so it corresponds to the offset to GMT. Is this the reason. I can of course just add 2 hours but want to understand why to make the script robust in the future.

Thanks for your help Jesper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` accepts a `datetime` object so you could just do (pandas assumes UTC):

```
pd.to_datetime(datetime(2020, 5, 11))
```

You are getting a 2 hour offset when converting to a timestamp because by default python's `datetime` is unaware of timezone and will give you a "naive" `datetime` object (docs are here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects). The generated timestamp will be in the local timezone, hence the 2 hour offset.

You can pass in a `tzinfo` parameter to the `datetime` object specifying that the time should be treated as UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pytz

pd.to_datetime(datetime(2020, 5, 11, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.UTC).timestamp()*1e9)
```

Alternatively, you can generate a UTC timestamp using the `calendar` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import calendar

timestamp = calendar.timegm(datetime(2020, 5, 11, 0, 0, 0).utctimetuple())
pd.to_datetime(timestamp*1e9)
```

Answer (score 1):

if your datetime objects actually represent *local time* (i.e. your OS setting), you can simply use

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

t = pd.to_datetime(datetime(2020, 5, 11).astimezone())
# e.g. I'm on CEST, so t is
# Timestamp('2020-05-11 00:00:00+0200', tz='Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit')
```

see: [How do I get a value of datetime.today() in Python that is “timezone aware”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62342873/10197418)

---

Just keep in mind that `pandas` will treat naive Python datetime objects as if they were UTC:

```
from datetime import timezone

t1 = pd.to_datetime(datetime(2020, 5, 11, tzinfo=timezone.utc))
t2 = pd.to_datetime(datetime(2020, 5, 11))

t1.timestamp() == t2.timestamp()
# True
```

see also: [Python datetime and pandas give different timestamps for the same date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645239)