# How to localize datetime in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I've written below code in Python3.

```
import datetime as dt

a = dt.datetime(2020,7,24,9,0,0)
print(a)
```

This is showing below output.

```
2020-07-24 09:00:00
```

But it is not showing in localized format. Expected output should be as mentioned below as my timezone is 'Asia/Kolkata'.

```
2020-07-24 09:00:00+05:30
```

How to get this done?

Comment: That's not "localized", it just adds the time zone information. Localized would be something like 7/24 2020 (assuming your local convention is as crazy as the American one).

Comment: a = dt.datetime(2020,7,24,9,0,0, tzinfo=dt.timezone(dt.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)))

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the `pytz` module, to further localize it and also show the timezone, use the module `tzlocal`

```
pip install pytz tzlocal
```

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
from tzlocal import get_localzone

format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
# Current time in UTC
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
print(now_utc.strftime(format))
# Convert to local time zone
now_local = now_utc.astimezone(get_localzone()) # ie 'Asia/Kolkata'
print(now_local.strftime(format))
```

Output:

```
2020-07-25 07:05:50 UTC+0000
2020-07-25 12:35:50 IST+0530
```

Also a detailed answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530166/5668215).

Comment: I've written below code

a = dt.datetime(2020,7,24,9,0,0, tzinfo=timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print(a)

Output:
2020-07-24 09:00:00+05:53

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime as dt

a = dt.datetime(2020,7,24,9,0,0)
local_time = "+5:30"
print(str(a)+local_time)
```

output

```
2020-07-24 09:00:00+5:30
```