# How to convert s.ms intohh:mm:ss,mmm format

Tags: python, json, datetime

I am facing a problem with converting seconds.milliseconds into hh:mm:ss,mmm format in python.
Please refer to my code below.

```
with open('SubRip.srt','r',encoding='UTF-8') as f:

     json_data=json.load(f)
def ss2HMS(a):
   for i in json_data:
      import time
      
      var= float(a)
   return time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f',time.gmtime(var))
```

I am trying to fetch startTime from a SRT file( which I converted into a json file) and now again that I want to make its time into SRT format, I am just trying it to make into hh:mm:ss,mmm format.
The startTime in json is in seconds.millisecond format. I was able to get hh:mm:ss but not hh:mm:ss,mmm. milliseconds is not getting added. Does anybody have any idea about this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `time.gmtime` has no attribute for milliseconds. You can get the milliseconds from e.g. `161.1` seconds by taking the fractional part of the number and concatenating it to the output as follows.

```
>>> var = 161.1
>>> millisecs = str(var).split('.')[1][:3]
>>> millisecs
'1'
>>> time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.',time.gmtime(t)) + millisecs + '0' * (3-len(millisecs))
'00:02:41.100'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But there is one problem. The video's length is 2 minute and 45 seconds, but still it is showing 05:32:41.10000. I don't know why it is adding 5 hours and 30 minutes. Have you faced any similar issue like this?

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal That reminds me of [timezone issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-in-python-that-is-timezone-aware), but I guess the 30 minutes wouldn't make sense in this case. What is the input value and the desired output?

Comment: For example:- input value is 161.1 so the output should be 00:02:41,000. This is not precise, I am just giving an idea of how the output should look like. If you have seen a subtitle file, exactly same like that.

Comment: I have again edited the code, kindly look at it again.

Comment: I got the desired answer. The only problem now is that it is not coming in HH:MM:SS,Ms format. It is coming in H:MM:SS,Ms. One zero is missing from the beginning. The code that worked is below:                                                    import datetime
  
def convert(n):
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = n))
      
# Driver program
n = 12345
print(convert(n))