# Python datetime conversion from int datetime and vise versa

Tags: python

I am **new to Pythong** and trying to convert DateTime in Python to int then convert int back again to DateTime, but I am missing 2 hours exactly which I don't know why.

Code:

```
import datetime
import calendar
import time

def test_time_conversion():
        now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        time_now_decimal = calendar.timegm(now.timetuple())
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_now_decimal)
        time_expected_decimal = calendar.timegm(dt.replace(microsecond=0).timetuple())
        print("\n")
        print(now)
        print(time_now_decimal)
        print(dt)
        print(time_expected_decimal)
```

Output:

```
2021-11-17 14:49:39
1637160579
2021-11-17 16:49:39
1637167779
```

Comment: You're not missing 2 *minutes*, you're missing 2 *hours*. Due to timezone conversion.

Comment: @deceze But since I've not provided any values for the timezone I believe it must not change ...

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.now()` returns a *local, naïve* timestamp, i.e. 14:49 is your current wall clock time. `timegm` interprets this time as being in UTC (Greenwich mean time). And 14:49 in your timezone and 14:49 in Greenwich appears to have a 2 hour difference.

Comment: ... So use `dqtetime.utcnow()` instead of `datetime.now()`.

Comment: @MarkReed Even better, use [time zone aware dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4530069/247696). In Python 3.2+, you can run `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone()`

Comment: …and/or don't mix in weird functions like `timegm` which explicitly interpret dates in specific timezones. Either stay local for everything, or very explicitly handle timezones.

Comment: @deceze what do you suggest to do the jobs datetime -> number then number->datetime ?

Comment: @Adelin `datetime.fromtimestamp(datetime.now().timestamp())`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing 2 hours, not 2 minutes. It's because of timezone conversion.

datetime.now() returns timezone-naive (no timezone info saved) local time. Because of lack of timezone info, timestamp will get converted without adjusting, thus assuming the time is UTC.

Two fixes:

- Either pass timezone you want as argument to `datetime.now()`. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now). E.g. `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`
- Or use `datetime.utcnow()` to get (still timezone-naive) UTC before converting. This approach is not recommended because timezone-naive datetime is often interpreted as local time - [mentioned in all utc-but-naive methods in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow)