# How to make a datetime object aware (not naive)

Tags: python, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

**What I need to do**

I have a timezone-unaware datetime object, to which I need to add a time zone in order to be able to compare it with other timezone-aware datetime objects. I do not want to convert my entire application to timezone unaware for this one legacy case.

**What I've Tried**

First, to demonstrate the problem:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> unaware = datetime.datetime(2011,8,15,8,15,12,0)
>>> unaware
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12)
>>> aware = datetime.datetime(2011,8,15,8,15,12,0,pytz.UTC)
>>> aware
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> aware == unaware
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

First, I tried astimezone:

```
>>> unaware.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
>>>
```

It's not terribly surprising this failed, since it's actually trying to do a conversion.  Replace seemed like a better choice (as per [How do I get a value of datetime.today() in Python that is "timezone aware"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware)):

```
>>> unaware.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> unaware == aware
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
>>>
```

But as you can see, replace seems to set the tzinfo, but not make the object aware.  I'm getting ready to fall back to doctoring the input string to have a timezone before parsing it (I'm using dateutil for parsing, if that matters), but that seems incredibly kludgy.

Also, I've tried this in both Python 2.6 and Python 2.7, with the same results.

**Context**

I am writing a parser for some data files. There is an old format I need to support where the date string does not have a timezone indicator. I've already fixed the data source, but I still need to support the legacy data format. A one time conversion of the legacy data is not an option for various business BS reasons. While in general, I do not like the idea of hard-coding a default timezone, in this case it seems like the best option. I know with reasonable confidence that all the legacy data in question is in UTC, so I'm prepared to accept the risk of defaulting to that in this case.

Comment: `unaware.replace()` would return `None` if it were modifying `unaware` object inplace. The REPL shows that `.replace()` returns a new `datetime` object here.

Comment: What I needed when I came here: `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)`

Comment: @MartinThoma I would use the named `tz` arg to be more readable: `datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)`

Comment: `astimezone()` can now (starting with 3.6) be called on a naive object, and its parameter can (starting with 3.3) be omitted, so the solution is as simple as `unaware.astimezone()`

Comment: I found the trick : Europe/Paris, Berlin, CET, ... are completety bugged in pytz and I was in a mess of instability for months because of that.
I replaced all that by dateutil.tz.gettz(...) and now my code is stable and works !
My advice : abandon completely pytz !

Answer (score 865, accepted):

In general, to make a naive datetime timezone-aware, use the [localize method](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

```
import datetime
import pytz

unaware = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0)
aware = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0, pytz.UTC)

now_aware = pytz.utc.localize(unaware)
assert aware == now_aware
```

For the UTC timezone, it is not really necessary to use `localize` since there is no daylight savings time calculation to handle:

```
now_aware = unaware.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

works. (`.replace` returns a new datetime; it does not modify `unaware`.)

Comment: Well, I feel silly.  Replace returns a new datetime.  It says that right there in the docs too, and I completely missed that.  Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: "Replace returns a new datetime." Yep. The hint that the REPL gives you is that it's showing you the returned value. :)

Comment: thanks, I had use from dt_aware to unware
dt_unware = datetime.datetime(*(dt_aware.timetuple()[:6])),

Comment: if the timezone is not UTC then don't use the constructor directly: `aware = datetime(..., tz)`, use `.localize()` instead.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that local time may be ambiguous. `tz.localize(..., is_dst=None)` asserts that it is not .

Comment: looking at pytz source, `localize` simply calls `.replace(tzinfo= ... )` provided you called it on an unaware `datetime`; anything else throws an exception.  I don't see anything about it doing calculations.

Comment: ah...  I found it.  :)  It does that for `pytz.utc.localize`, but some of the other timezones do calculations.

Comment: @TimTisdall: Right. For timezones which are subclasses of `DstTzInfo`, `localize` is defined [like this](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~stub/pytz/devel/view/head:/src/pytz/tzinfo.py#L244).

Comment: A simple one-liner to copy the timezone info from the aware to the unaware object - independently of the timezone: ```unaware = aware.tzinfo.localize(unaware)```. This implies however that the aware object has pytz timezone object.

Comment: This didn't actually work for me. I found that it's actually just setting the timezone to UTC -- which is wrong if you are not on UTC time.

Comment: What is the difference between using [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) and just setting `unaware.tzinfo = datetime.timezone.utc`?

Comment: @Jens: There isn't much difference, except that one is a function call and the other is an assignment.

Comment: putz has a bug that sets Amsterdam timezone to + 20 minutes to UTC, some archaic timezone from 1937. You had one job pytz.

Comment: ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)

Comment: I found the trick : Europe/Paris, Berlin, CET, ... are completety bugged in pytz and I was in a mess of instability for months because of that.
I replaced all that by dateutil.tz.gettz(...) and now my code is stable and works !
My advice : abandon completely pytz !

Answer (score 423):

All of these examples use an external module, but you can achieve the same result using just the datetime module, as also presented in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662061/943773):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt = datetime.now()
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

print(dt.isoformat())
# '2017-01-12T22:11:31+00:00'
```

Fewer dependencies and no pytz issues.

NOTE: If you wish to use this with python3 and python2, you can use this as well for the timezone import (hardcoded for UTC):

```
try:
    from datetime import timezone
    utc = timezone.utc
except ImportError:
    #Hi there python2 user
    class UTC(tzinfo):
        def utcoffset(self, dt):
            return timedelta(0)
        def tzname(self, dt):
            return "UTC"
        def dst(self, dt):
            return timedelta(0)
    utc = UTC()
```

Comment: Very good answer for preventing the `pytz` issues, I'm glad I scrolled down a bit! Didn't want to tackle with `pytz` on my remote servers indeed :)

Comment: Note that `from datetime import timezone` works in py3 but not py2.7.

Comment: You should note that `dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)` returns a new datetime, it does not modify `dt` in place. (I will edit to show this).

Comment: How might you, instead of using timezone.utc, provide a different timezone as a string (eg "America/Chicago")?

Comment: @rapt For python2 you may miss the `from datetime import tzinfo` when defining `utc` in the except path.

Comment: i think this answer is wrong: timezones change over time! eg. "Europe/Vienna" once hat an offset of "01:05", so setting it with `replace()` would offset the datetime by that, and not the current offset of "01:00".

resulting in weirdness like `>>> tz.normalize(datetime.strptime('2019-02-12', '%Y-%m-%d').replace(tzinfo=tz)).isoformat()
'2019-02-12T23:55:00+01:00'`

better use localize: `>>> tz.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-02-12', '%Y-%m-%d')).isoformat()
'2019-02-12T00:00:00+01:00'`

Comment: @bumpkin better late than never, i guess: `tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')`

Comment: @bumpkin I couldn't find a way to do it without using pytz.

Comment: You can save a line and do `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` , as in ufficial doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow

Comment: +1 for pure Python solution. BTW, another way of doing it via a one-liner is `datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 26), datetime.datetime.min.time(), datetime.timezone.utc)`

Comment: @bumpkin and whoever wants to do this without using `pytz`: the `timezone` object takes a timedelta object. So, for example, thes will work `datetime.now(timezone(timedelta(hours=1))).isoformat()` `datetime.now(timezone(timedelta(hours=-1))).isoformat()`

Answer (score 119):

I wrote this Python 2 script in 2011, but never checked if it works on Python 3.

I had moved from dt_aware to dt_unaware:

```
dt_unaware = dt_aware.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

and dt_unware to dt_aware:

```
from pytz import timezone
localtz = timezone('Europe/Lisbon')
dt_aware = localtz.localize(dt_unware)
```

Comment: you could use `localtz.localize(dt_unware, is_dst=None)` to raise an exception if `dt_unware` represents non-existing or ambiguous local time (note: there were no such issue in the previous revision of your answer where `localtz` was UTC because UTC has no DST transitions

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian , first comment applied

Comment: I appreciate you showing both directions of the conversion.

Comment: @Sérgio and when you put that argument in .replace and get "TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'"? What can be done for this problem?

Answer (score 60):

**Python 3.9 adds the [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) module** so now only the standard library is needed!

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from datetime import datetime
unaware = datetime(2020, 10, 31, 12)
```

Attach a timezone:

```
>>> unaware.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Asia/Tokyo'))
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 31, 12, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Tokyo'))
>>> str(_)
'2020-10-31 12:00:00+09:00'
```

Attach the system's local timezone:

```
>>> unaware.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('localtime'))
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 31, 12, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='localtime'))
>>> str(_)
'2020-10-31 12:00:00+01:00'
```

Subsequently it is properly converted to other timezones:

```
>>> unaware.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('localtime')).astimezone(ZoneInfo('Asia/Tokyo'))
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 31, 20, 0, tzinfo=backports.zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Tokyo'))
>>> str(_)
'2020-10-31 20:00:00+09:00'
```

[Wikipedia list of available time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

---

**Windows** [has no](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html#data-sources) system time zone database, so here an extra package is needed:

```
pip install tzdata
```

---

There is a backport to allow use of `zoneinfo` in **Python 3.6 to 3.8**:

```
pip install backports.zoneinfo
```

Then:

```
from backports.zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
```

Comment: on Windows, you also need to `pip install tzdata`

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for the tip! I'll test this tomorrow and it to my answer. Do you know what the situation is on Macs?

Comment: @xjcl You need `pip install tzdata` on any platform where the operating system doesn't provide a time zone database. Macs should work out of the box. It will not hurt to install `tzdata` unconditionally (since the system data is prioritized over `tzdata`) if your application needs time zone data.

Comment: @Paul That's unfortunate since I was really hoping for a standard library solution

Comment: @xjcl tzdata is effectively part of the standard library (we call it a "first party package"), you just need to pip install it because it has a much faster release cadence than CPython.

Comment: I wanted to mention, it's very easy to add this to requirements.txt conditionally for Windows only: `tzdata; sys_platform == "win32"` (from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614580/705296)

Answer (score 53):

I use this statement in Django to convert an unaware time to an aware:

```
from django.utils import timezone

dt_aware = timezone.make_aware(dt_unaware, timezone.get_current_timezone())
```

Comment: I do like this solution (+1), but it is dependent on Django, which is not what they were looking for (-1). =)

Comment: You don't actually the second argument. The [default argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) (None) will mean the local timezone is used implicitly. Same with the DST (which is the third argument_

Comment: If you want to convert to UTC:
`dt_aware = timezone.make_aware(dt_unaware, timezone.utc)`

Answer (score 27):

I agree with the previous answers, and is fine if you are ok to start in UTC. But I think it is also a common scenario for people to work with a tz aware value that has a **datetime that has a non UTC local timezone.**

If you were to just go by name, one would probably infer replace() will be applicable and produce the right datetime aware object.  This is not the case.

**the replace( tzinfo=... ) seems to be random in its behaviour**.  It is therefore useless. Do not use this!

localize is the correct function to use. Example:

```
localdatetime_aware = tz.localize(datetime_nonaware)
```

Or a more complete example:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
pytz.timezone('Australia/Melbourne').localize(datetime.now())
```

gives me a timezone aware datetime value of the current local time:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 3, 7, 44, 51, 908574, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Australia/Melbourne' AEDT+11:00:00 DST>)
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes, trying to do `replace(tzinfo=...)` on a timezone other than UTC will foul up your datetime. I got `-07:53` instead of `-08:00` for instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994611/1224827

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example of `replace(tzinfo=...)` having unexpected behavior?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasted a lot of time trying to use `replace()` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can anyone explaim `<DstTzInfo 'Australia/Melbourne' AEDT+11:00:00 DST>` to me?
What does it mean?

Comment: @SorryformybadEnglish i think that's the `repr()` of a timezone object, giving different representations. the text name (`'Australia/Melbourne'`), the code (`AEDT` - Australian Eastern Daylight Time), the offset from UTC (`+11:00:00`), and i guess if daylight saving time is enabled (`DST`)

Answer (score 13):

Use [`dateutil.tz.tzlocal()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzlocal) to get the timezone in your usage of [`datetime.datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) and [`datetime.datetime.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

unlocalisedDatetime = datetime.now()

localisedDatetime1 = datetime.now(tz = tz.tzlocal())
localisedDatetime2 = datetime(2017, 6, 24, 12, 24, 36, tz.tzlocal())
localisedDatetime3 = unlocalisedDatetime.astimezone(tz = tz.tzlocal())
localisedDatetime4 = unlocalisedDatetime.replace(tzinfo = tz.tzlocal())
```

Note that `datetime.astimezone` will first convert your `datetime` object to UTC then into the timezone, which is the same as calling `datetime.replace` with the original timezone information being `None`.

Comment: If you want to make it UTC: `.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.UTC)`

Comment: One import less and just: `.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`

Answer (score 10):

This codifies @Sérgio and @unutbu's [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065242/623735). It will "just work" with either a `pytz.timezone` object or an [IANA Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) string.

```
def make_tz_aware(dt, tz='UTC', is_dst=None):
    """Add timezone information to a datetime object, only if it is naive."""
    tz = dt.tzinfo or tz
    try:
        tz = pytz.timezone(tz)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return tz.localize(dt, is_dst=is_dst)
```

This seems like what `datetime.localize()` (or `.inform()` or `.awarify()`) should do, accept both strings and timezone objects for the tz argument and default to UTC if no time zone is specified.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me "brand" a raw datetime object as "UTC" without the system first assuming it to be local time and then recalculating the values!

Answer (score 10):

for those that just want to make a timezone aware datetime

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 7, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

for those that want a datetime with a non utc timezone *starting in python 3.9 stdlib*

```
import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 7, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles"))
```

Comment: How is this different to the main answer?

Comment: I don't care to use the localize function. This answer is more succinct for those trying to solve their problem quickly (what I wish was the accepted answer).

Comment: The localize function is just there to test the assert method right? It's not actually required? `aware = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0, pytz.UTC)` is the same as you've written they have just named the parameter no?

Comment: the assert is there to demonstrate how to change a datetime between timezone aware and unaware. _I_ actually provided the keyword argument for clarity. you can omit the keyword and rely on positional arguments if you prefer. kwargs are less error prone though.

Comment: So the only difference is the using the named parameter?

Comment: and the assert and the extra paragraphs. Again, the point of my answer is for a quick solution if someone reaches this question looking to make a timezone aware datetime.

Comment: tzinfo named parameter is not mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: you don't even need `pytz` for this; use `datetime.timezone.utc` instead.

Comment: What if you want a timezone other than UTC?

Comment: with pytz,
```
from pytz import timezone
eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 7, tzinfo=eastern)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yet another way of having a `datetime` object NOT naive:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 22, 51, 16, 219942, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be much higher than the other answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Changing between timezones

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

other_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')

# From random aware datetime...
aware_datetime = datetime.utcnow().astimezone(other_tz)
>> 2020-05-21 08:28:26.984948+02:00

# 1. Change aware datetime to UTC and remove tzinfo to obtain an unaware datetime
unaware_datetime = aware_datetime.astimezone(pytz.UTC).replace(tzinfo=None)
>> 2020-05-21 06:28:26.984948

# 2. Set tzinfo to UTC directly on an unaware datetime to obtain an utc aware datetime
aware_datetime_utc = unaware_datetime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
>> 2020-05-21 06:28:26.984948+00:00

# 3. Convert the aware utc datetime into another timezone
reconverted_aware_datetime = aware_datetime_utc.astimezone(other_tz)
>> 2020-05-21 08:28:26.984948+02:00

# Initial Aware Datetime and Reconverted Aware Datetime are equal
print(aware_datetime1 == aware_datetime2)
>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

quite new to Python and I encountered the same issue. I find this solution quite simple and for me it works fine (Python 3.6):

```
unaware=parser.parse("2020-05-01 0:00:00")
aware=unaware.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzlocal()).astimezone(tz.tzlocal())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to minimize changes to your code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

start_utc = datetime.utcnow()
print ("Time (UTC): %s" % start_utc.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

> Time (UTC): 09-01-2021 03:49:03

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Africa/Cairo')
start_tz = datetime.now().astimezone(tz)
print ("Time (RSA): %s" % start_tz.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

> Time (RSA): 09-01-2021 05:49:03

Comment: just be aware that `datetime.utcnow()` does not return a timezone aware datetime (in contrast to its name)

Answer (score 0):

In the format of unutbu's answer; I made a utility module that handles things like this, with more intuitive syntax. Can be installed with pip.

```
import datetime
import saturn

unaware = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0)
now_aware = saturn.fix_naive(unaware)

now_aware_madrid = saturn.fix_naive(unaware, 'Europe/Madrid')
```

Answer (score 0):

- As per the documentation [`datetime.utcnow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow):

  - > **Warning:** Because naive `datetime` objects are treated by many `datetime` methods as local times, it is preferred to use aware datetimes to represent times in UTC. As such, the recommended way to create an object representing the current time in UTC is by calling [`datetime.now(timezone.utc)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).
  - This option is covered in other answers, but the document citation is not.
- As per the documentation [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

  - > **Warning:** Because naive `datetime` objects ... by calling [`datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=timezone.utc)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp).
  - This option is not covered in other answers.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import time  # for timestamp
import pytz  # for aware comparison

now = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
aware = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second, now.microsecond, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

print(now == aware)
[out]: True

fts = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time(), tz=timezone.utc)
aware = datetime(fts.year, fts.month, fts.day, fts.hour, fts.minute, fts.second, fts.microsecond, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

print(fts == aware)
[out]: True
```

Answer (score -4):

Above all mentioned approaches, when it is a [Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/), there is a very simple solution using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

unix_timestamp = 1513393355
pst_tz = pd.Timestamp(unix_timestamp, unit='s', tz='US/Pacific')
utc_tz = pd.Timestamp(unix_timestamp, unit='s', tz='UTC')
```