# Python datetime and daylight saving

Tags: python, datetime

My code uses `datetime.now()` to get current date and time. The problem is that time is 1 hour behind due to daylight saving.

How can I get "real" current time (same I see in system's clock)

Thanks

Comment: How do you define "real" time anyway? ;-)  The answer posted seems to define "real" time as "unix time" which almost matches UTC time.  If you want localtime with DST, then datetime.now() should help.  At least it's consistently giving me "correct" time here (CEST).

Comment: On my screen I see current date and time ()July 9; 5:49pm - datetime.now returns July 9, 4:49pm

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986776/how-do-you-convert-a-naive-datetime-to-dst-aware-datetime-in-python

Comment: Strange, when I ran `datetime.datetime.now()` at 5:14 CDT, I got `datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 9, 17, 14, 30, 672000)`. Maybe there's something about your system that is affecting the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the current system time, you could try the `time` module. `time.time()` would give you a unix timestamp of the current system time.

**Edit**: In response to the OP's comment

Use `time.strftime()` and `time.localtime()` to interface with `datetime` objects and your DB

Comment: Hi, I need datetime as difference is calculated with a variable from db

Comment: time.* returns time only; I need date as well

Comment: Incorrect. `time.localtime()` returns a `time tuple`: `time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=14, tm_min=47, tm_sec=40, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=191, tm_isdst=1)`. You should really lookup the documentation to make sure that you are correct

Answer (score 0):

You should read [python's datetime doc up to section 8.1](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) where an example is given on how to achieve what you want.

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
ZERO = timedelta(0)
HOUR = timedelta(hours=1)

# A UTC class.
class UTC(tzinfo):
    """UTC"""

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO
utc = UTC()
datetime.now(utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be completely off, but in case the time in the BIOS your computer is set to UTC (thus the difference of one hour to local time)

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

should yield the time you're looking for.