# converting time from UTC to CST

Tags: python-3.x, timezone, python-datetime, strftime, pytz

I am trying to convert UTC time to CST. But I am not getting the output as expected.

Below is my code:

```
import datetime
import pytz
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
e = pytz.timezone('US/Central')

time_from_utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(1607020200))
time_from = time_from_utc.astimezone(e)
time_from.strftime(fmt)
time_to_utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(1609785000))
time_to = time_to_utc.astimezone(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
print(time_from_utc)
print(time_from)
print(time_to_utc)
print(time_to)
```

Here is the output:

```
(base) ranjeet@casper:~/Desktop$ python3 ext.py 
2020-12-03 18:30:00
2020-12-03 07:00:00-06:00
2021-01-04 18:30:00
2021-01-04 07:00:00-06:00
```

I was expecting that after conversion, I should get time corresponding to the time of UTC i.e.

```
2020-12-03 18:30:00
2020-12-03 12:30:00-06:00
```

since CST is -6 Hours from UTC.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had a look at this and running your code on my local laptop and online in a repl and i get the output you expect. Have you tried running your code else where. Maybe its a local issue with the machine where the code is running.

Comment: I am trying to convert DateTime with timezone. Like naive date object to timezone aware. But I am failing. I tried it on different machines as well, with different venv but I am getting the same result.

Comment: Note: [Stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the problem** is that

```
time_from_utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(1607020200))
```

gives you a naive datetime object - which Python treats as local time by default. Then, in

```
time_from = time_from_utc.astimezone(e)
```

things go wrong since **`time_from_utc` is treated as *local* time.** Instead, set UTC explicitly when calling [fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
e = pytz.timezone('US/Central')

time_from_utc = datetime.fromtimestamp(1607020200, tz=timezone.utc)
time_from = time_from_utc.astimezone(e)
time_from.strftime(fmt)
time_to_utc = datetime.fromtimestamp(1609785000, tz=timezone.utc)
time_to = time_to_utc.astimezone(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
```

- which will give you

```
2020-12-03 18:30:00+00:00
2020-12-03 12:30:00-06:00
2021-01-04 18:30:00+00:00
2021-01-04 12:30:00-06:00
```

**Final Remarks:** with Python 3.9, you have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), so you don't need a third party library for handling of time zones. [Example usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64484063/10197418).