# Timezone Timestamp Weirdness

Tags: python, linux, timezone, ubuntu-20.04, pytz

I am finding a very strange behavior for different timezones in Python.  The following code:

```
import datetime as dtm
import pytz


def test_tz():
    america_ny_tz: dtm.tzinfo = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
    est_tz: dtm.tzinfo = pytz.timezone("EST5EDT")

    today = dtm.date.today()

    ny_dtm = dtm.datetime(
        year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day, tzinfo=america_ny_tz
    )
    est_dtm = dtm.datetime(
        year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day, tzinfo=est_tz
    )

    print(f"New York: {ny_dtm.timestamp()}, EST: {est_dtm.timestamp()}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_tz()
```

outputs:

```
New York: 1609995360.0, EST: 1609995600.0
```

As you may notice the difference is about 4 minutes where one would have to assume the time should be the same.

Am I accessing time zone information incorrectly or is my understanding that the Time Zone information should be the same?

Running on Linux, Ubuntu 20.04 but the behavior on 18.04 was the same.

P.S.  I haven't tried other languages or different OSs to see if the behavior will be the same.

Comment: Concerning your p.s., the issue you encountered is library-specific, not OS-specific. same trouble on Windows ;-) And by the way, notice [this comment](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/846c3ac7abc246094dd754ac6dc90423148a5107/northamerica#L188) from Mr. Olson in the db - `EST5EDT` is obsolete.

Comment: @MrFuppes I know that `EST5EDT` is obsolete but it is still in use, hence my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to localize correctly - with `pytz`'s timezone objects, setting `tzinfo` directly when creating the datetime object is *not* the right way. It's [in the docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

> This library only supports two ways of building a localized time. The first is to use the localize() method provided by the pytz library.

and

> The second way of building a localized time is by converting an existing localized time using the standard astimezone() method

---

On the other hand, if you happen to use Python 3.9+, you can use the `zoneinfo` module from the standard lib to make you life easier - see [the docs / using-zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#using-zoneinfo) or [example usage here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64484063/10197418).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be because one timezone uses Local Mean Time and the other is an offset of UTC (Universal Coordinated Time).

```
>>> pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>
>>> pytz.timezone("EST5EDT")
<DstTzInfo 'EST5EDT' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>
>>> pytz.timezone("LMT")
```

From https://www.timeanddate.com/time/local-mean-time.html

> Local Mean Time was officially used as civil time in many countries
> during the 19th century. Each city had a different local time defined
> by its longitude, the difference amounting to 4 minutes per degree
> longtitude. This equals a distance of 50 miles or 81 kilometers on New
> York's latitude.

Comment: if you don't call localize, pytz falls back to using the first entry for the timezone in its database - which happens to be LMT.

Comment: @MrFuppes and is supposed to have stopped in [late 19th century](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/846c3ac7abc246094dd754ac6dc90423148a5107/northamerica#L357)