# Python: How to check if date is ambiguous?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-dateutil

Is there any simple way, how to determine if date in a datetime object is ambiguous - meaning that particular datetime could exist twice in a particular timezone in order of regular time change?

Here is an example of ambiguous datetime object. In New York timezone, on 5th November 2017 2 AM, time was shifted back to 1 AM.

```
import datetime
import dateutil

# definition of time zone
eastern_time = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/New_York')

# definition of ambiguous datetime object
dt = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 5, 1, 30, 0, tzinfo=eastern_time)
```

I expect something like this.

```
>>> suggested_module.is_dt_ambiguous(dt)
True
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994611/4834) answer help at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`datetime_ambiguous`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.datetime_ambiguous) function, which applies during a backward transition (such as end of DST in the fall).

```
dateutil.tz.datetime_ambiguous(dt, eastern_time)
```

You might also be interested in [`datetime_exists`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.datetime_exists), which applies during a forward transition (such as start of DST in the spring).

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!