# Default datetime string format with timezone

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm using the default python datetime string format with a JSON webservice.

Then, I'm trying to compare it with an actual datetime. And I'm also using timezone with `pytz.utc`.

Here is my string date:

```
print date
2013-02-26 21:28:37.261134+01:00
```

Trying to convert my string into a datetime (edit for timezone with `pytz`):

```
if datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+%Z') < datetime.now(pytz.utc):
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
ValueError: time data '2013-02-26 21:28:37.261134+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%Z'
```

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax for the `strptime` format, to use my date ?

Comment: You cannot compare the aware timezone with `datetime.now()` though, you'll have to give the latter a timezone too. See [How to make an unaware datetime timezone aware in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7065164)

Comment: You're right about the duplicate, thank you. Google gave me nothing... For the timezone, I was actually using `datetime.now(pytz.utc)` in my code. Sorry for the misleading....

Answer (score 7):

Basically that's because the datetime module doesn't know ahead of time about what the available timezones are. It's kind of lame.

I recommend using [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). It's a third party package, but it parses your string out the door.

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2013-02-26 21:28:37.261134+01:00')                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 26, 21, 28, 37, 261134, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```