# how to get records for a day relative to timezone in django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-timezone

I am trying to all the record for a certain day with the following:

```
entered_at = request.session['entered_at']
entered_at = datetime.strptime(entered_at, "%m-%d-%Y")
day_start = entered_at.replace(hour=00, minute=00)
day_end = entered_at.replace(hour=23, minute=59)

entries = Entry.objects.filter(
                                                  customer=customer, 
                                                  entered_at__lt=day_end, 
                                                  entered_at__gte=day_start
                                                  )
```

When I do this I get the following warning in my console:

> DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is
>   active.

I know I can add something like: , `day_start = entered_at.replace(hour=00, minute=00, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

however, this will not make the range from midnight to 11:59pm relative to the users timezone if I use UTC.

How can I express a full day relative to the users timezone?

Comment: So, if I'm reading this right, you're trying to figure out how to get the user's time zone based on the web request?

Comment: @jrothenbuhler No I have the users timezone stored (los_angeles). I want to use that for the filter above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like this, using the pytz library. See [How to make an unaware datetime timezone aware in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python):

```
import pytz

entered_at = request.session['entered_at']
entered_at = datetime.strptime(entered_at, "%m-%d-%Y")
day_start = entered_at.replace(hour=00, minute=00)
day_end = entered_at.replace(hour=23, minute=59)

timezone = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
day_start = timezone.localize(day_start)
day_end = timezone.localize(day_end)

entries = Entry.objects.filter(customer=customer, 
                               entered_at__lt=day_end, 
                               entered_at__gte=day_start)
```