# What does Django Date filter mean by 'Naive'?

Tags: python, django, date, django-template-filters

I want to use the `'c'` date format with the Django date filter. That format references 'naive' dates. I don't want to have timezones in my template (that's held elsewhere in my xml).

I'm not sure what that is, the documentation for django doesn't mention it, nor does the [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) it references.

What is it, and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation refers to python dates, of these [available types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types).

> An object of type time or `datetime` may be naive or aware. A `datetime`
>   object `d` is aware if `d.tzinfo` is not None and `d.tzinfo.utcoffset(d)`
>   does not return `None`. If `d.tzinfo` is `None`, or if `d.tzinfo` is not `None`
>   but `d.tzinfo.utcoffset(d)` returns `None`, *d* is naive. A `time` object *t* is
>   aware if `t.tzinfo` is not `None` and `t.tzinfo.utcoffset(None)` does not
>   return `None`. Otherwise, *t* is naive.

So naive just means it does not have any time zone information.

To make something 'aware' follow this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065242/1075247) by [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu):

> In general, to make a naive datetime timezone-aware, use the [localize
>   method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types):
>
> ```
> import datetime
> import pytz
>
> unaware = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0)
> aware = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0, pytz.UTC)
>
> now_aware = pytz.utc.localize(unaware)
> assert aware == now_aware
> ```
>
> For the UTC timezone, it is not really necessary to use `localize`
>   since there is no daylight savings time calculation to handle:
>
> ```
> now_aware = unaware.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
> ```
>
> works. (`.replace` returns a new datetime; it does not modify
>   `unaware`.)

To make it unaware set the timezone to `None`.