# Django Python datetime difference not working

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a model `Player` which contains a `DateTimeField` called `time_joined`. I am trying to find the time elapsed since `time_joined`, so I do:

```
curr_time = datetime.now()
print(player.time_joined)
print(curr_time)
print(curr_time - player.time_joined)
print('done')
```

The output from this block of code is:

```
2015-08-22 20:51:02.965000+00:00
2015-08-29 10:07:35.933000
```

And then it stops outputting anything, for some reason that I don't understand.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you get any error? Is `player.time_joined` datetime aware or naive object?

Comment: I didn't get an error. I don't know what datetime aware or naive means.

Comment: what is the value you get for `player.time_joined.tzinfo`

Comment: This is happening because you are subtracting aware and naive objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is happening because you are subtracting naive and aware datetimes.**

From the [tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) section:

> An object of type [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) or [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) may be naive or aware. A datetime
>   object `d` is aware if `d.tzinfo` is not `None` and `d.tzinfo.utcoffset(d)`
>   does not return `None`. If `d.tzinfo` is `None`, or if `d.tzinfo` is not `None`
>   but `d.tzinfo.utcoffset(d)` returns `None`, `d` is naive. A time object `t` is
>   aware if `t.tzinfo` is not `None` and `t.tzinfo.utcoffset(None)` does not
>   return `None`. Otherwise, `t` is naive.

You can't subtract aware and naive datetimes. You have to either change both to naive or both to aware datetime to perform subtraction.

Let us try to subtract aware and a naive datetimes in the shell and see the results.

```
In [10]: aware_datetime # an aware datetime having timezone info
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 19, 23, 57, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [11]: current_naive_datetime = datetime.now()

In [12]: current_naive_datetime # naive datetime having no timezone info
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 29, 20, 50, 2, 350872)

In [13]: print(current_naive_datetime - aware_datetime)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-2b7ea8141c3e> in <module>()
----> 1 print(current_naive_datetime - aware_datetime)

TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

**Solution-1 : Convert aware datetime `aware_datetime` to naive datetime**

To perform the subtraction, you can convert `aware_datetime` object to naive by replacing its `tzinfo` with `None`.

```
In [14]: my_naive_datetime = aware_datetime.replace(tzinfo=None)

In [15]: my_naive_datetime
Out[15]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 19, 23, 57, 56)

In [16]: print(current_naive_datetime - my_naive_datetime)
374 days, 20:52:06.350872
```

**Solution-2: Convert naive datetime `datetime.now()` to aware datetime**

```
In [17]: import pytz

In [18]: aware_current_datetime = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

In [19]: aware_current_datetime
Out[19]: datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 29, 21, 21, 44, 227886, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [20]: print(aware_current_datetime - aware_datetime)
374 days, 21:23:48.227886
```

(I don't know as to why you are not getting an error as i am able to get an error on my machine.)

Comment: So how can I make them the same type?

Comment: Updated the ans with a solution. Check if it helps.

Comment: So it turns out that Django has a option in settings.py whether or not to use timezone. By commenting out USE_TZ = True, I was able to make my program work. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Yes, you can do that also. But remember that Django will use naive datetimes in local time then.

Comment: Is there a way to get an aware datetime for datetime.now()?

Comment: Yes, you can use `datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)` to get an aware datetime. I have included it in the ans.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this. Please comment for any details. Enjoy!!

```
import datetime
curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print curr_time
2015-08-29 10:22:57.878721
```

after few secs......

```
future_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print future_time
2015-08-29 10:23:55.188854
```

I hope this what you are trying to accomplish!!

```
print future_time-curr_time
0:00:57.310133
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to use the datetime from the Django model Player. I understand how to find the difference between two datetimes in general, but I need to know why it is not working in this specific situation.

Comment: Basically curr_time (which you defined) has not timezone info in it. But player.time_joined is a Django defined based on timezone. This is the source of conflict.

Comment: But how do I make curr_time have a timezone

Comment: Please follow these links below:
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-python-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-python-stand
3. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow