# Django: DateTimeField received a naive datetime

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-datetime, django-timezone

I am working on creating a view that will only display posts whose deadlines dates have not passed. accomplish this I've added the following my views.py file:

```
current_posts = Posts.objects.filter(post_name=post, deadline__range=[date.today(), "2999-12-31"]).order_by('deadline')
```

This way I am able to only show posts whose deadline range fall between today and December 31, 2999. However I get the following error, and no posts show at all:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField OfferedFunds.deadline received a naive datetime (2999-12-31 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

Past solutions posted left me trying the following which also does not work:

```
timezone.now()
current_posts = Posts.objects.filter(post_name=post, deadline__range=[timezone.now(), "2999-12-31"]).order_by('deadline')
```

What does work is if instead of entering: timezone.now(), I enter an actual date like "2015-10-10" however this defeats the purpose. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking a range, you can do `deadline__gte=timezone.now()`

This page has more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#gte

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this problem today at work! Basically the `deadline__range=[date.today(), '2999-10-10']` line has a UTC aware time in the first slot and a UTC unaware time in the second slot. Let me guide you to the post that helped me [How to make an unaware datetime timezone aware in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python). There are some pure python solutions and some django solutions but I think you'll find what you need there!

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` set `USE_TZ = False`, so that should fix the warning. In my case I wanted to work with native datetime globally so that's what I ended up doing. Cheers!