# how to split a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

how do i split the 'datetime' column into 'date' column and 'time' column?
I would like to have the 'date' as column 1 and 'time' as column 2.
The rest of the columns will have the same header.

```
 datetime                  C     H     L     O  OI  V    WAP  
0  2017-03-13 19:00:00  8.22  8.22  8.10  8.10   4  6  8.143   
1  2017-03-13 19:01:00  8.22  8.22  8.22  8.22   0  0  8.220   
2  2017-03-13 19:02:00  8.22  8.22  8.22  8.22   0  0  8.220   
3  2017-03-13 19:03:00  8.22  8.22  8.22  8.22   0  0  8.220   
4  2017-03-13 19:04:00  8.22  8.22  8.22  8.22   0  0  8.220   


print(df.head())
new_date_and_time = lambda x : x.split()
df['new_date_and_time'] = df['datetime'].apply(new_date_and_time)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting timestamp column into seperate date and time columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595710/splitting-timestamp-column-into-seperate-date-and-time-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column is already a "datetime" datatype you could just call the dataframe method "dt" on the original column and reassign to new columns:

```
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['datetime'].dt.time
# optional, drop original column
df.drop('datetime', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Obviously dropping the date time column is optional.