# Splitting datetime in csv to separate date and time columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

I'm new to python 3 I have to get a datetime value from a .csv file and split into a separate date and time value column.

csv file:

```
C1,C2,V2,Time_Stamp
0.1,1.3,-0.9,13/6/2017 14:42
0.1,1.2,-0.9,13/6/2017 14:42
0.1,1.3,-0.9,13/6/2017 14:42
0.1,1.3,-0.9,13/6/2017 14:42
```

Initially, what I have is this under Time_Stamp:

**Output** after running:

```
timestamps = Data.Time_Stamp
for i in timestamps:
    dataobj = dt.datetime.strptime(i, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") #Time_Stamp datetime format - need set varibale to print
    print (dataobj) #Prints the following output
```

**Output**:

> 13/6/2017 14:42
>
> 13/6/2017 14:42
>
> 13/6/2017 14:42
>
> 13/6/2017 14:42
>
> 13/6/2017 14:42

Based on the above output, it has date and time together in a column, I want the date to be in a different column and the time to be in another.

```
   13/6/2017 14:42    13/6/2017   14:42

   13/6/2017 14:42    13/6/2017   14:42

   13/6/2017 14:42    13/6/2017   14:42

   13/6/2017 14:42    13/6/2017   14:42

   13/6/2017 14:42    13/6/2017   14:42
```

I tried following examples from this [Splitting timestamp column into seperate date and time columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595710/splitting-timestamp-column-into-seperate-date-and-time-columns) but i could not get similar outputs.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 
import datetime as dt

print (row)

Data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('csv_date.csv')
print (Data)

timestamps = Data.Time_Stamp
for i in timestamps:
    dataobj = datetime.strptime(i, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

df['new_date'] = [i.date() for i in Data['Time_Stamp']]
df['new_time'] = [i.time() for i in Data['Time_Stamp']]
```

Error I faced:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-ca9ed5c25ff2> in <module>()
----> 1 df['new_date'] = [i.date() for i in Data['Time_Stamp']]
      2 df['new_time'] = [i.time() for i in Data['Time_Stamp']]

<ipython-input-137-ca9ed5c25ff2> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df['new_date'] = [i.date() for i in Data['Time_Stamp']]
      2 df['new_time'] = [i.time() for i in Data['Time_Stamp']]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading, use `pd.read_csv` with `parse_dates` and `infer_datetime_format` as `True`.

```
Data = pd.read_csv('csv_date.csv', parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Next, you can just extract the date & time:

```
Data['Date'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.date
Data['Time'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.time
```

Comment: I've tried using the examples you provided but i had this error : **TypeError: cannot convert an object of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to a datetimelike index** as well as **AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values**

Comment: @SanctaIgnis Please post some of your input data.

Comment: I added the data I'm using with the datetime

Comment: @SanctaIgnis Fixed, and it works now. Use `parse_dates=['Time_Stamp']` instead

Comment: @SanctaIgnis No problemo. Future reference, data always always helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('csv_date.csv')
Data['new_times'] = Data['Time_Stamp'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
```

use apply and lambda deal with Dataframe

Comment: I tried the above example you provided. I encountered this error **module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'** Any idea why?

Comment: datetime.datetime.strptime() and you can use pd.to_datetime() tranform the column