# How to separate a transaction column in a dataframe to different columns(day,month,time, year)?

Tags: pandas, datetime-format

```
Column is in this format :  Wed Dec 26 09:06:00 IST 2018
```

I want to separate in columns like Day,Month,Time,Time zone,Year in python

Comment: Please could you provide some more information, such as a sample of your dataframe. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595710/splitting-timestamp-column-into-separate-date-and-time-columns

Comment: are all the time zones `IST` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the str.split method with expand=True.
Make sure to rename the columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ["Wed Dec 26 09:06:00 IST 2018"]})
df = df.col.str.split(expand=True)
df.columns = ['Day','Month','Day of month', 'Time','Time zone','Year']
df
```

```
   Day Month Day of month      Time Time zone  Year
0  Wed   Dec           26  09:06:00       IST  2018
```