# I have a data frame with one column and I'd like to split it into two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with one column and I'd like to split it into two columns and

for example

```
   colonne 1
10/10/2020 00:03:00
10/10/2020 00:07:00 ....
```

and i want it to be like that :

```
date          hour 
10/10/2020    00:03:00 ....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting timestamp column into separate date and time columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595710/splitting-timestamp-column-into-separate-date-and-time-columns)

Comment: What is the data type of the column in your original dataframe?  (use `df.dtypes`)

Comment: If your column are strings, use `df["colonne 1"].str.split(expand=True)`.

Comment: just as a note, when you do this your `hour` column won't be a timestamp object anymore.