# How to split date-time and place in a new column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have a column with 4000 time data in this format

```
             Time
 2021-11-02T09.13.39.156+0000   
 2021-12-02T09.13.23.679+0000
 .....
 2022-01-09T09.29.29.696+0000
```

I can access month, year by this

```
df['Time'][0].month
df['Time'][0].year
```

But I want to have three new columns with `month-year`, `month`, `year`.

Can anyone please suggest me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35595908/17978261) what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you sure about `09.13.39.156` and not `09:13:39.156`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) accessor:

```
df = df.assign(**{'month-year': df['Time'].dt.strftime('%m-%Y'),
                  'month': df['Time'].dt.month,
                  'year': df['Time'].dt.year})
print(df)

# Output
                              Time month-year  month  year
0 2021-11-02 09:13:39.156000+00:00    11-2021     11  2021
1 2021-12-02 09:13:23.679000+00:00    12-2021     12  2021
2 2022-01-09 09:29:29.696000+00:00    01-2022      1  2022
```