# Converting into date-time format in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need help converting into python/pandas date time format. For example, my times are saved like the following line:

```
2017-01-01 05:30:24.468911+00:00
.....
2017-05-05 01:51:31.351718+00:00
```

and I want to know the simplest way to convert this into date time format for essentially performing operations with time (like what is the range in days of my dataset to split up my dataset into chunks by time, what's the time difference from one time to another)? I don't mind losing some of the significance for the times if that makes things easier. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you saving those as strings? If so, you can use `strptime()` to break out the time indicated into an object and do operations on members of those objects.

The members of the objects will be determined by the formatting string you pass into the method. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html#time.strptime) documentation for more information.

Comment: Yes, they are saved as strings. Sorry for not specifying. I'll try strptime(). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timestamp` will convert it for you.

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 05:30:24.468911+00:00')
Timestamp('2017-01-01 05:30:24.468911+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Let's say you have a dataframe that includes your timestamp column (let's call it `stamp`).  You can use `apply` on that column together with `Timestamp`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stamp': ['2017-01-01 05:30:24.468911+00:00',
               '2017-05-05 01:51:31.351718+00:00']})
>>> df
    stamp
0   2017-01-01 05:30:24.468911+00:00
1   2017-05-05 01:51:31.351718+00:00

>>> df['stamp'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
0   2017-01-01 05:30:24.468911+00:00
1   2017-05-05 01:51:31.351718+00:00
Name: stamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

You could also use `Timeseries`:

```
>>> pd.TimeSeries(df.stamp)
0    2017-01-01 05:30:24.468911+00:00
1    2017-05-05 01:51:31.351718+00:00
Name: stamp, dtype: object
```

Once you have a [Timestamp](http://0%20%20%202017-01-01%2005:30:24.468911+00:00%201%20%20%202017-05-05%2001:51:31.351718+00:00%20Name:%20stamp,%20dtype:%20datetime64[ns,%20UTC]) object, it is pretty efficient to manipulate.  You can just difference their values, for example.

You may also want to have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python) which discusses timezone unaware values to aware.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say I have two strings `2017-06-06` and `1944-06-06` and I wanted to get the difference (what Python calls a `timedelta`) between the two.

First, I'll need to `import datetime`. Then I'll need to get both of those strings into `datetime` objects:

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-06-06', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> b = datetime.datetime.strptime('1944-06-06', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

That will give us two datetime objects that can be used in arithmetic functions that will return a `timedelta` object:

```
>>> c = abs((a-b).days)
```

This will give us `26663`, and `days` is the largest resolution that `timedelta` supports: [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Since the Pandas tag is there:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['2017-01-01 05:30:24.468911+00:00'])
df.columns = ['Datetime']
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', utc=True)
print(df.dtypes)
```