# Why is converting this datetime to Epoch off by 30 minutes?

Tags: python, datetime, epoch

I have the following string representing a UTC timestamp: `2017-12-03T20:38:00.971261Z`

I would like to convert it into Posix timestamp (IE: seconds since the epoch)
Using this online converter (https://www.epochconverter.com/) I know the answer is `1512333480`

But when I do the following code, the result is off by 1800 seconds -- 30 minutes:

```
>>> temp_time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-03T20:38:00.971261Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
>>> ctime = int(datetime.datetime(temp_time1.year,
                                  temp_time1.month,
                                  temp_time1.day,
                                  temp_time1.hour,
                                  temp_time1.minute,
                                  temp_time1.second,
                                  temp_time1.microsecond,
                                  pytz.timezone('Europe/London')).strftime('%s'))
>>> print ctime
1512351480
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here??

Comment: So why are you using the Europe/London timezone if this is supposed to be a UTC timestamp?

Comment: `temp_time1.timestamp()` produces `1512333480.971261`.

Comment: There is no method timestamp() on a datetime object. Am I totally confused Martijn??

Comment: But there is such a method; I linked to the documentation it in my answer.

Comment: Ah, it is new in Python 3.3. Are you using Python 2 perhaps?

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover that situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a *new timestamp* and put it in the Europe/London timezone. That is not the same thing as UTC. The Europe/London timezone from the PyTZ database includes *historical* offsets, and those affect how `datetime.datetime()` interprets the timezone.

Just use the [`datetime.timestamp()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) on the `datetime` object you already parsed from the string:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> temp_time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-03T20:38:00.971261Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
>>> temp_time1.timestamp()
1512333480.971261
```

Your original `temp_time1` datetime object is timezone agnostic, so the `timestamp()` object already assumes no timezone conversion has to take place.

If you must apply the `Europe/London` timezone first for whatever reason, then at least use the [`timezone.localize()` method](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) to get the right offset applied:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(temp_time1)
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 3, 20, 38, 0, 971261, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' GMT0:00:00 STD>)
>>> pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(temp_time1).timestamp()
1512333480.971261
```

See [How to make an unaware datetime timezone aware in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python)

For Python 2 and Python 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2, where `datetime.timestamp()` is not available, subtract the epoch date:

```
>>> (temp_time1 - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
1512333480.971261
```

Add in the `UTC` timezone when dealing with timezone-aware `datetime` instances:

```
>>> (pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(temp_time1) - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
1512333480.971261
```

Combined into a function:

```
def datetime_to_timestamp(dt, epoch=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)):
    if dt.tzinfo is not None:
        epoch = pytz.utc.localize(epoch)
    return (dt - epoch).total_seconds()
```