# Python convert string to datetime in variable formats

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am generating date and time information which is string from an API. The generated string is in your system's date/time format by default (Win 10 in my case). For example if you are using MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt in your computer, the generated string would be something like "05/07/2019 06:00:00 AM".

For comparison purpose, I would then convert the string to datetime format by using `datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`. This works prefectly fine, however if someone else whose system date/time format is different from' MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS tt' runs my script, he would get a mismatch error as the string can no longer be converted by `%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p`.

So would it be possible to make the desired datetime format become a variable argument in the strptime function? Or even simpler, just make the format to be the same as the system's date/time format.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python

Comment: You should generate an unambiguous string, that is choose a format once for all. (In IT world, "unambiguous" means often "US"). Workaround: ship the format with the string if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try and except to fix this (although there might be another way)

```
try:
  datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
except TypeError:
  try:
     datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
  except:
     try:
         datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%d/%m/%y %I:%M:%S %p")
# and so on....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that is what I did so far. However there are way more than these 2 kinds of formats.

Comment: You can also keep going like
try: something 
except:
try: something
except: