# How do parse a time with changing timezones

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to parse the following time:

```
 mytime = "11:32  PM LT"
 datetime.strptime(mytime,  '%H:%M %p LT')
```

But sometimes "11:32  PM LT" is a GMT time like for example "18:32  PM GMT". How do I parse that correctly so both time types are taken into consideration?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python

Comment: if you can put timezone as an offset then you use %z as datetime.strptime(mytime,  '%H:%M %p %z')

Answer (score 1):

Please try the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.

```
parse('11:32  PM GMT')
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 26, 23, 32, tzinfo=tzutc())
```