# How to convert an unaware datetime to UTC time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert an unaware datetime to UTC time in Python.

I have:

- datetime
- location (latitude and longitude)

I am finding the timezone of my datetime based on the location with

`tz.timezone_at(lat=latitude, lng=longitude)`

I am now trying to attach this timezone to my datetime to be able to convert it after to UTC.
However I am failing at this step.

I have tried:

`interview_slot = interview_slot.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(store_timezone))`

But unable to import the library that allows me to use ZoneInfo. Do you have another way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python)

Moreover, pytz should be firstly installed from cmd like this: `pip install pytz`