# all the datetime fields are added 7 hours

Tags: python, odoo-12

I want to ask about the datetime field in odoo, if all the datetime fields are added 7 hours, what is the reason ? This is happening on the client server, my display is normal,. thank you in advance

```
date_order = fields.Datetime('Order Date', required=True, states=READONLY_STATES, index=True, copy=False, default=fields.Datetime.now,\
        help="Depicts the date where the Quotation should be validated and converted into a purchase order.")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuxuK.png)

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Client server is in a different time zone than you. You need to use time zone aware datetime.

See this link for more info: [How to make a timezone aware datetime object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-a-timezone-aware-datetime-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Odoo stores Datetime fields as UTC times and the displayed time depends on your client's timezone.

The timezone can be set in the user preferences menu