# How do I get website to display local time?

Tags: python, django, time, localtime

If I run this in VS Code, it gives me the correct local time:

```
from time import strftime
time = strftime("%H:%M %p")
print(time)
```

But if I use the same code in a Django project, my website displays a time which is 8 hours behind local time.

```
from time import strftime,localtime

def time_display(request):
    context = {
        "date":strftime("%b %d, %Y",localtime()),   #DOESN'T DISPLAY LOCAL TIME
        "time1": strftime("%H:%M %p",localtime()),  #DOESN'T DISPLAY LOCAL TIME
        "time3": strftime("%H:%M %p"),              #DOESN'T DISPLAY LOCAL TIME
    }
    return render(request,'time_display.html',context)
```

How do I fix it to display correct local time where the webpage is being viewed?

Comment: `localtime` would return local time of the server. You should get the loıcation/timezone of the browser and create a time object with timezone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-a-timezone-aware-datetime-object-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but you can change `setting.py` file like:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
```

`note:` change `Europe/London` to your time zone.

You can find a list of timezone names here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones