# Python - Time Convert from UTC to CEST

Tags: python, time

I have following part of script:

```
time = datetime.strptime(msg['timestamp'].split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

msg['timestamp'] is string.
I would like to converted this time to CEST.
Do you have any ideas?

Best Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a timezone aware datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-a-timezone-aware-datetime-object)

Comment: I saw the link earlier but i can't put it all together. Finally I use this 
`time = datetime.strptime(msg['timestamp'].split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')  timestamp = time+ timedelta(hours=2) `

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use this

`time = datetime.strptime(msg['timestamp'].split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')  timestamp = time+ timedelta(hours=2)`