# Convention on how to interpret a datetime with UTC information and what do Pandas localize and convert functions do with it?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I'm sorry if this not the right place to post, but I have a large dataset of dates from a database, all of which are in the following format, localized to my timezone which is UTC +2:

`2023-04-11 10:14:34+02:00`

My question is, what is the usual convention: does the above date mean:

1. **in my timezone** the hour for that date is `10:14:34`
2. **in my timezone** the hour is `12:14:34`?
3. **in my timezone** the hour is `8:14:34`?

From what I gather from the answer of xjcl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-a-datetime-object-aware-not-naive), the standard is to interpret my date as option 1). However, the function `tz_localize' in python's pandas would convert the date above to 3), while pandas'` tz_convert` gives 1). So, which is the right way to interpret my date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2023-04-11 10:14:34+02:00` is a date-time-offset string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339) format, both of which prefer that the date and time components are separated with a letter `T`, but *permit* using a space character instead (which is what you have).

In this format, the offset describes how the date and time values are related to UTC.

In your example, the date is `2023-04-11`, the time is `10:14:34`, and that point is two hours ahead of UTC.   The corresponding UTC time would thus be two hours earlier, `8:14:34`.

None of this has anything to do with *your* local time zone.  You can absolutely evaluate timestamps with a `+02:00` offset regarless of whether your own local time zone offset is `+02:00` or `+05:30` or `-08:00`, etc.  Your local time zone is not relevant to the interpretation of the timestamp.

As for your question about the behavior of `tz_localize` and `tz_convert`, I suspect you are not considering at which point your `datetime` values are "naive" and when they are "aware".  Naive `datetime` values in python don't contain any time zone information, thus if you convert them to "aware" values, then a conversion is going to be performed between two time zones - probably your local time zone and UTC.  As to which direction the conversion happens depends very much on exactly what you do in your code (which you didn't supply in the question).

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer and especially for naming the standard, I wasn't able to find it. As far as I understood, pandas' `to_datetime` function will interpret a date in ISO 8601 as "aware"; in any case, I applied that function with default arguments to dates in ISO 8601 (given as strings) and was then looking to get "naive" dates in my timezone. I wasn't considering the other direction, from "naive" to "aware".

Comment: Keep in mind that ISO 8601 is really a _collection_ of standard formats for date and time.  This specific one within that standard is called _"Complete representation for calendar date and time of day"_, in the _"extended format"_ variant.  It's defined in section 5.4.2.1 of the ISO 8601-1:2019 standard, or section 4.3.2 of the older ISO 8601:2004 standard (assuming one has actually purchased a copy of the standard). Since it generally matches RFC 3339, which is freely available, sometimes it's easier to reference it that way instead.