# Passing date time in a different format to models.DateTimeField in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I have a model that looks something like this

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    ...
```

I have to fill the database with chunks of data. I am getting the data in form of a flat json string (no nesting) so my work is pretty easy i.e.

```
mydict = json.loads(jsonstr)
mypost = Post(**mydict) 
mypost.save()
```

there is just one issue that the date-time is expressed in "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+zzzz" format ( e.g.  `"created" : "2011-11-17T09:21:31+0000"` ) which breaks the above code.

I know `forms.DateTimeField` has `input_formats`. Is there a way I could make DateTimeField accept above format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subclass DateTimeField and convert the value appropriately:

```
class ConvertingDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(datetime.strptime(value, FORMAT_STRING))
```

Then use ConvertingDateTimeField to replace models.DateTimeField.

There's probably a better way to do it if you look how DateTimeField creates the datetime object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I knew I had to subclass DateTimeField but couldn't find the method to override. It really helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) and override the `created` form field instead of going directly to your model.

Something like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    created = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000',))
    class Meta:
        model = Post

mydict = ...

form = PostForm(mydict)
if not form.is_valid():
    # handle appropriately for your app
    raise Exception

instance = form.save() # or use 'commit=False' if you don't want to save to DB
```

Unfortunately, I don't think `strptime` supports the GMT offset hence why I've hard-coded it in the `input_format`.  You may be able to override the 'clean' method for that field if you want to scrub it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the DateTimeField expects a timezone-naive datetime, so you need to [strip off the (+zzzz) part.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/python-cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes/796019#796019)

```
naive = dt.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Applies to Python 2.x only.

Comment: striping off the timezone info does not solve my problem completely i would still need to do a bunch of string operations before django accepts it, which i am looking to avoid that's why i asked the question in the first place

Comment: It's sad that python has such poor support for timezone info. I mean it is simple enough to convert date time to gmt for saving into any database. But, I still love python :)

Answer (score 0):

ok this is what i did finally :

```
class MyDateTimeFeild(models.DateTimeField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        from dateutil.parser import parse
        from datetime import timedelta
        td = float(value[-5:])/100
        timediff = timedelta(hours=td)
        return parse(value).replace(tzinfo=None) - timediff
```

thanks every one!! :) all posts were very helpfull.