# Django check elapsed time

Tags: python, django

I am writing an URL shortener application in Django. Where i want to check whether a URL is expired or not (URL is only valid for 3 hours). Below is my models.py but it is not working 
I am getting error `can't subtract datetime object`

```
import uuid
import base64
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

def _generateShortUrl():
    """
        This function will generate base64 encoded id
    """
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes)[:6]


class link(models.Model):
    """
        This is a link class 
    """
    link = models.URLField()                                    # To store user entered URL
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)                       # How many hits for particular URL
    last_used = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)             # When URL is last used 
    short_url = models.CharField(max_length=6,unique=True)      # base64 URL encoded id  

    def linkValidate(self):
        timediff = datetime.datetime.now() - self.last_used                       
        return timediff.min

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Custom Save method for link model 
        """
        self.short_url = _generateShortUrl()        
        super(link, self).save(*args, **kwargs)   


class user_info(models.Model):
    """
        This is a user_info class 
    """
    user_agent = models.TextField()                 # Stores user_agent name used by user
    user_ip = models.ManyToManyField(link)          # Stores user's IP

    def userIP(self):
        """Method to return tags related to store"""
        return ','.join([t.link for t in self.link.all()])

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

class linkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
        link admin class
    """
    list_display = ('link','hits','short_url','last_used',
                    'linkValidate')
    ordering = ('hits',)

class userInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
        user_info admin class
    """
    list_display = ('user_agent','userIP')

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
admin.site.register(link,linkAdmin)
admin.site.register(user_info,userInfoAdmin)
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Do you have time zone support enabled? `USE_TZ` in settings is `True`?

Comment: I imagine someone will beat me to the real fix for your question, but I have to ask... aren't you playing with fire that your URL's are going to be unique for the first 4ish letters?

Comment: `@alecxe` it is there in my settings.py ...`@Foon` thanks for the tip i will fix it ....

Comment: @user2217267 actually, I may have misspoke a little... I ran a quick test in which I generated lots of uids... using :6, I still haven't had a collision.  6 bytes works out (after doing 3/4 due to base64 encoding) to 36 bits, 2^36 = 68719476736; even taking account the birthday paradox, your odds are pretty good it'll be a while before there's a problem if you're deleting them after 3 hours).   Second comment... did you mean .min to be minutes (which is what I interrupted it as) or did you just mean to return a big negative while you were debugging

Comment: I actually wanted to return the number of hours elapsed ......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have time zone support enabled, `self.last_used` is a timezone-aware datetime object, `datetime.datetime.now()` is not.

Try this instead:

```
timediff = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self.last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Another option is to make your `now()` timezone-aware using `make_aware()`:

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(), timezone.get_default_timezone())
timediff = now() - self.last_used
```

Also see:

- [Can't subtract datetime and timestamp in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594314/cant-subtract-datetime-and-timestamp-in-django)
- [django 1.4 - can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652819/django-1-4-cant-compare-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes)
- [django 1.4 timezone.now() vs datetime.datetime.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783864/django-1-4-timezone-now-vs-datetime-datetime-now)