# Convert numpy.datetime64 to string object in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, numpy

I am having trouble converting a python `datetime64` object into a string. For example:

```
t = numpy.datetime64('2012-06-30T20:00:00.000000000-0400')
```

Into:

```
'2012.07.01' as a  string. (note time difference)
```

I have already tried to convert the `datetime64` object to a `datetime` long then to a string, but I seem to get this error:

```
dt = t.astype(datetime.datetime) #1341100800000000000L
time.ctime(dt)
ValueError: unconvertible time
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64 help your specific problem?

Comment: thanks, solution was:

import pandas as pd
 ts = pd.to_datetime(str(date))
 d = ts.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

Comment: there is a simpler way, take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 96):

Solution was:

```
import pandas as pd 
ts = pd.to_datetime(str(date)) 
d = ts.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason. numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: @chemeng you need to run `pd.to_datetime` on the `numpy.datetime64` object before doing `.strftime`

Comment: downvoted as it does not work with all values of datetime64 (for example, `pd.to_datetime(np.datetime64('0000-01-01T00:00:00.000', 'ms'))` returns `Timestamp('1969-12-31 06:43:52.780800')` , i.e. casts the type to datetime64[ns] silently). np.datetime_as_string (see jgrant's answer) works with all cases, and the name makes more sense to boot, I swear the pd.to_datetime is named for maximum confusion. Mind you, it will work in most common cases...

Answer (score 57):

If you don't want to do that conversion gobbledygook and are ok with just one date format, this was the best solution for me

```
str(t)[:10]
Out[11]: '2012-07-01'
```

As noted this works for pandas too

```
df['d'].astype(str).str[:10]
df['d'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # equivalent
```

Comment: That is madness! What a creative solution!

Comment: This works on a [pandas.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html) object as well, which is good for keeping nanosecond, or smaller, precision, as `strftime` does not support this level of precision.

Answer (score 56):

You can use Numpy's `datetime_as_string` function. The `unit='D'` argument specifies the precision, in this case days.

```
 >>> t = numpy.datetime64('2012-06-30T20:00:00.000000000-0400')
 >>> numpy.datetime_as_string(t, unit='D')
'2012-07-01'
```

Comment: `numpy` instead of `numpyp`.
Or with `import numpy as np` just `np.datetime...`.

Comment: This is a great way to do it!

Comment: The real answer. No pandas needed, full support for time units other than 'ns' (meaning it has no problem with times way before BC in 'ms' resolution, like pandas.Timestamp), and overall "clearly the intended way"

Answer (score 10):

`t.item().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')`

`.item()` will cast `numpy.datetime64` to `datetime.datetime`, no need to import anything.

Comment: This is a bit confusing because `datetime64[ns]` item returns an integer in nanoseconds since 1970.  One fix is `t.astype('datetime64[s]').item().strftime()`

Comment: No. datetime64.item() will convert into int seconds.

Answer (score 5):

There is a route without using pandas; but see caveat below.

Well, the `t` variable has a resolution of nanoseconds, which can be shown by inspection in python:

```
>>> numpy.dtype(t)
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

This means that the integral value of this value is 10^9 times the UNIX timestamp. The value printed in your question gives that hint. Your best bet is to divide the integral value of `t` by 1 billion then you can use `time.strftime`:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d", time.gmtime(t.astype(int)/1000000000))
2012.07.01
```

In using this, be conscious of two assumptions:

1) the datetime64 resolution is nanosecond

2) the time stored in datetime64 is in UTC

*Side note 1*: Interestingly, the numpy developers decided [1] that `datetime64` object that has a resolution greater than microsecond will be cast to a `long` type, which explains why `t.astype(datetime.datetime)` yields `1341100800000000000L`. The reason is that `datetime.datetime` object can't accurately represent a nanosecond or finer timescale, because the resolution supported by `datetime.datetime` is only microsecond.

*Side note 2*: Beware the different conventions between numpy 1.10 and earlier vs 1.11 and later:

- in numpy <= 1.10, datetime64 is stored internally as UTC, and printed as local time. Parsing is assuming local time if no TZ is specified, otherwise the timezone offset is accounted for.
- in numpy >= 1.11, datetime64 is stored internally as timezone-agnostic value (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 in unspecified timezone), and printed as such. Time parsing does not assume the timezone, although `+NNNN` style timezone shift is still permitted and that the value is converted to UTC.

[1]: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/datetime.c see routine `convert_datetime_to_pyobject`.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622388/778533) I would do the following:

```
import numpy
import datetime
t = numpy.datetime64('2012-06-30T20:00:00.000000000')
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t.item() / 10**9).strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
```

The division by a billion is to convert from nanoseconds to seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted an ISO 8601 formatted string without needing any extra dependencies. My numpy_array has a single element as a datetime64. With help from @Wirawan-Purwanto, I added just a bit:

```
from datetime import datetime   

ts = numpy_array.values.astype(datetime)/1000000000
return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).isoformat() # "2018-05-24T19:54:48"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a one liner** (note the padding with extra zero's):

```
datetime.strptime(str(t),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

*code sample*

```
import numpy
from datetime import datetime

t = numpy.datetime64('2012-06-30T20:00:00.000000000-0400')
```

*method 1:*

```
datetime.strptime(str(t),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

*method 2*:

```
datetime.strptime(str(t)[:10], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

*output*

```
'2012-07-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if someone want to apply same formula for any series of datetime dataframe then you can follow below steps

```
import pandas as pd

temp = []
for i in range(len(t["myDate"])):                                                       
       ts = pd.to_datetime(str(t["myDate"].iloc[i])) 
       temp.append(ts.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    
t["myDate"] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

- datetime objects can be converted to strings using the **str**() method

```py
t.__str__()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will handle `np.datetime64` objects of any units:

```py
dt = np.datetime64('2002-06-08T00:00:00.000000000')
format_str = "%a, %d %b %Y"

formatted_str = dt.astype('datetime64[us]').item().strftime(format_str)
```

`.astype('datetime64[us]')` is required because if the resolution is `datetime64[ns]` (nanoseconds - the default for Pandas in many cases) or smaller, then `.astype(datetime)` returns an int. 'us' (microseconds) is the smallest unit that gets converted to a Python datetime.

`.item()` returns "a standard Python scalar", usually this means a `float` or `int`, but with dates it returns a Python `datetime` (depending on the unit), so you can get the right object without importing anything. `.astype('O')` also works.

Reference, this GitHub issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19782#issuecomment-908318335