# How to change format of a numpy array of date from YYYY-MM-DD to MM - YY

Tags: python

I have the following date list:

```
[datetime.date(2021, 9, 30), datetime.date(2021, 10, 31),
 datetime.date(2021, 11, 30), datetime.date(2021, 12, 31),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 31), datetime.date(2022, 2, 28)]
```

Which I store in an array:

```
NDateArray = np.array(DateList,dtype=np.datetime64)

['2021-09-30' '2021-10-31' '2021-11-30' '2021-12-31' '2022-01-31'
 '2022-02-28']
```

Ho do I convert these to

```
'Sept 21' 'Oct 21' 'Nov 2021' ....
```

Comment: And you don't just want to format the original list of `datetime.date` instances  as strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't call strftime on numpy.datetime64, no definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327101/cant-call-strftime-on-numpy-datetime64-no-definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

DateList = [datetime.date(2021, 9, 30), datetime.date(2021, 10, 31),
 datetime.date(2021, 11, 30), datetime.date(2021, 12, 31),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 31), datetime.date(2022, 2, 28)]

NDateList = [np.datetime64(x) for x in DateList]

for i in range(0,len(NDateList)):
    mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(NDateList[i]), '%Y-%m-%d')
    print(mydate.strftime('%b, %y'))
```

**Output :**

```
Sep, 21
Oct, 21
Nov, 21
Dec, 21
Jan, 22
Feb, 22
```

If you want fullname for month and a year as YYYY, you can do  `print(mydate.strftime('%B, %Y'))`

**Output :**

```
September, 2021
October, 2021
November, 2021
December, 2021
January, 2022
February, 2022
```

**Or**

if i want to keep what you did in your code you can continue like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

DateList = [datetime.date(2021, 9, 30), datetime.date(2021, 10, 31),
 datetime.date(2021, 11, 30), datetime.date(2021, 12, 31),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 31), datetime.date(2022, 2, 28)]

NDateArray = np.array(DateList,dtype=np.datetime64)

NDateList =  [str(x.astype('datetime64[D]')) for x in NDateArray]

NewArrayDate = []
for i in range(0,len(NDateList)):
    mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(NDateList[i]), '%Y-%m-%d')

    # append result to new array
    NewArrayDate.append(mydate.strftime('%b, %y'))


print(NewArrayDate)
```

Comment: They already have `np.datetime64` instances, not strings, as input, so they don't need to (and can't) use `strptime`.

Comment: I edit my answer. it will be correct now

Comment: @AchrafBenSalah If you replace the print by `NDateList[i]= mydate.strftime('%b-%y')` it throw the following error :
`ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "Sep-21" at position 0` How do you store it in this array ?

Comment: check the last code.