# Python Pandas Datetime and dataframe indexing issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `datetime` issue where I am trying to match up a `dataframe` 
    with dates as index values.

For example, I have `dr` which is an array of `numpy.datetime`.

```
dr = [numpy.datetime64('2014-10-31T00:00:00.000000000'),
      numpy.datetime64('2014-11-30T00:00:00.000000000'),
      numpy.datetime64('2014-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'),
      numpy.datetime64('2015-01-31T00:00:00.000000000'),
      numpy.datetime64('2015-02-28T00:00:00.000000000'),
      numpy.datetime64('2015-03-31T00:00:00.000000000')]
```

Then I have dataframe with `returndf` with dates as index values

```
print(returndf) 
             1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
10/31/2014  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11/30/2014  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Please ignore the missing values

Whenever I try to match date in `dr` and dataframe `returndf`, using the following code for just 1 month `returndf.loc[str(dr[1])]`,
I get an error

> `KeyError: 'the label [2014-11-30T00:00:00.000000000] is not in the [index]'`

I would appreciate if someone can help with me on how to convert `numpy.datetime64('2014-10-31T00:00:00.000000000')` into `10/31/2014` so that I can match it to the data frame index value.

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert numpy.datetime64 to string object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502506/convert-numpy-datetime64-to-string-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your index for `returndf` is not a `DatetimeIndex`.  Make is so:

   ```
   returndf = returndf.set_index(pd.to_datetime(returndf.index))
   ```
2. Your `dr` is a list of Numpy `datetime64` objects.  That bothers me:

   ```
   dr = pd.to_datetime(dr)
   ```
3. Your sample data clearly shows that the index of `returndf` does not include all the items in `dr`.  In that case, use `reindex`

   ```
   returndf.reindex(dr)

                1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
   2014-10-31 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   2014-11-30 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   2014-12-31 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   2015-01-31 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   2015-02-28 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   2015-03-31 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   ```

Comment: That was very help. But I am confused about datetime a bit. Here are the steps before the variable dr                                                              data_date = pd.to_datetime(testdf["Date"], format ="%m/%d/%Y")                           df=sorted(data_date.unique())  data_date seems to be correct but why does using sorted and unique convert df into datetime64?

Comment: You've got several things going on in there.  `sorted` is a python function and returns a list.  Also, you have `df = sorted(data_date.unique())`.  The `unique()` method will return a numpy array.  Not to mention don't even know what `data_date` is.  That wasn't in your original question.  Next: you don't call `pd.to_datetime` on a dataframe unless that dataframe has specifically named columns and if it does have those columns, you don't need to use the `format` argument.  If you want more clarity, post a new question.  Not enough room in comments.