# string and datetime object interchange

Tags: python, string, datetime, numpy

I have a bunch of strings indicate time in this format '2012-10-25'. I want to perform addition to it, for instance, add one day to '2012-10-25', I want to get '2012-10-26'. Do I have to change the string into a datetime object to do this? And how should I do it?

Suppose I've done it, and now I want to assign this new string to a numpy.narray. I tried:

```
pad = numpy.zeros((1,2), dtype=numpy.str)
padd[0,0]='2012-10-26'
```

but padd[0,0] only has '2', which means it only got the first byte in the string. I wonder what's wrong here and how to fix it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it without any additional packages:

```
import datetime
import numpy

time_string = '2012-10-26'

date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%d')

print str(date_object)
later_date_object = date_object + datetime.timedelta(0,3) # days, seconds, then other fields.
print str(later_date_object)

pad = numpy.zeros((1,2), dtype='object')
pad[0,0] = time_string

print pad[0,0]
```

note that you need to specify `dtype='object'` for the numpy array.

Comment: thank you but I got: ImportError: cannot import name datetime

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: it's 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3]

Answer (score 1):

```
 from dateutil.parser import parse as parse_date
 from datetime import timedelta
 my_date = parse_date(string_date, dayfirst=False)
 my_date = (my_date + timedelta(hours=24))
```

http://snag.gy/hQy2R.jpg

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work, I got this message:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#145>", line 1, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse as parse_date;my_date = parse_date('2012-10-11', dayfirst=False);my_date = (my_date + 24)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

Comment: I don't know why. It says timedelta is not defined. but I can correctly import the package

Comment: oh, it works, thanks. but it's like: datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 12, 0, 0). and I need to get '2012-10-12'

Comment: check the answer once again,add this line *from datetime import timedelta*

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy.datetime64` type:

```
import numpy as np

assert np.__version__[:3] == '1.7'
pad = np.empty((1,2), dtype='datetime64[D]') #NOTE: empty
pad[0,0] = np.datetime64('2012-10-26', 'D')
print(pad[0,0]) # -> 2012-10-26
pad[0,0] += np.timedelta64(1, 'D') # add 1 day
print(pad[0,0]) # -> 2012-10-27
```

Beware the [`datetime64` API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html) is *different* on *different* numpy versions.

See [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13703720/4279)