# Converting between datetime and Pandas Timestamp objects

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have the following:

```
> date1
Timestamp('2014-01-23 00:00:00', tz=None)

> date2
datetime.date(2014, 3, 26)
```

and I read on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753918/283296) that I could use `pandas.to_datetime()` to convert from `Timestamps` to `datetime` objects, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
> pd.to_datetime(date1)   
Timestamp('2014-01-23 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

Why? How can I convert between these two formats?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can use the to_pydatetime method to be more explicit:

```
In [11]: ts = pd.Timestamp('2014-01-23 00:00:00', tz=None)

In [12]: ts.to_pydatetime()
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 23, 0, 0)
```

It's also available on a DatetimeIndex:

```
In [13]: rng = pd.date_range('1/10/2011', periods=3, freq='D')

In [14]: rng.to_pydatetime()
Out[14]:
array([datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 10, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 11, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 12, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know that difference is between `to_datetime()` and `to_pydatetime()` and why passing a `Timestamp` object to the class method `pd.to_datetime` doesn't work?

Comment: @user815423426 it works on the global names function (pd.to_datetime(ts))... difference is that to_pydatetime returns a datetime :)

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to be be valid anymore.

Answer (score 31):

*Pandas Timestamp to datetime.datetime:*

```
pd.Timestamp('2014-01-23 00:00:00', tz=None).to_pydatetime()
```

*datetime.datetime to Timestamp*

```
pd.Timestamp(datetime(2014, 1, 23))
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('2014-01-23 00:00:00', tz=None).to_datetime()
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 23, 0, 0)
>>> pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2014, 3, 26))
Timestamp('2014-03-26 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks - I guess one should run `to_datetime` as an object method, but not as a class method, but why?

Comment: @user815423426 it seems contrary to its name `pd.to_datetime` always returns `Timestamp`

Comment: doesn't work on pandas 0.24. says `'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'`

Comment: @Phoenix, the method you are looking for is `to_pydatetime()`.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question of going from an existing python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) to a pandas [Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) do the following:

```
    import time, calendar, pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    
    def to_posix_ts(d: datetime, utc:bool=True) -> float:
        tt=d.timetuple()
        return (calendar.timegm(tt) if utc else time.mktime(tt)) + round(d.microsecond/1000000, 0)
    
    def pd_timestamp_from_datetime(d: datetime) -> pd.Timestamp:
        return pd.to_datetime(to_posix_ts(d), unit='s')
    
    dt = pd_timestamp_from_datetime(datetime.now())
    print('({}) {}'.format(type(dt), dt))
```

Output:

```
(<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>) 2020-09-05 23:38:55
```

I was hoping for a more elegant way to do this but the `to_posix_ts` is already in my standard tool chain so I'm moving on.