# Pandas Convert Timestamp Column to Datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

Given the following data frame and necessary wrangling:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c'],
        'dates':['2015-08-31 00:00:00','2015-08-24 00:00:00','2015-08-25 00:00:00']})
df.dates=df.dates.astype(str)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.dates.str.split(',\s*').str[0])
set(df['dates'])
```

I end up with:

```
{Timestamp('2015-08-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-08-25 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-08-31 00:00:00')}
```

I need to convert the time stamps back to datetime (really, just date) format.

I've tried this based on the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825349/converting-between-datetime-and-pandas-timestamp-objects):

```
df['dates'].to_pydatetime()
```

But that returns:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'
```

In my real data, the data type is: `<M8[ns]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting between datetime and Pandas Timestamp objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825349/converting-between-datetime-and-pandas-timestamp-objects)

Comment: Please see edited post. I tried the method suggested in that post but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) to return a `datetime.date` object:

```
In [3]:
set(df['dates'].dt.date)

Out[3]:
{datetime.date(2015, 8, 24),
 datetime.date(2015, 8, 25),
 datetime.date(2015, 8, 31)}
```

Comment: This extract only the date from the timestamp, not the entire datetime.

Answer (score 8):

You can convert directly using apply:

```
df.dates = df.dates.apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

This makes an in-place conversion of the previous 'dates' (as a timestamp) to the truncated 'datetime' only portion

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue where I need to convert timestamp to datetime in numpy though, but I believe it can be apply in Pandas as well.
I think using function under **Pandas.Timestamp** would be better to convert timestamp as below.

==============================

```
np1=pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(df2)
print(np1)
[[Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00') 'UCHITEC'  2000 2.56 5129.54]
 [Timestamp('2019-01-16 00:00:00') 'UCHITEC'  1000 2.61 2618.79]]

np2= np.asarray(np1)
Timestamp('2019-01-16 00:00:00')

np3 = pd.Timestamp.to_datetime64(np2[0][0])
np4 = pd.Timestamp.to_pydatetime(np2[1][0])

print(np3)
print(np4)

2019-01-31T00:00:00.000000000
2019-01-16 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are keen on extracting only the date from a given `Timestamp` object, you can get the raw `datetime.date` objects by calling the unbound `Timestamp.date` method as shown:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp, Series, date_range

start = Timestamp('2016-01-01')
stop = Timestamp('2016-01-02')
s = Series(date_range(start, stop, freq = 'H'))

print s[0]
2016-01-01 00:00:00

print s.map(Timestamp.date)[0]
2016-01-01
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me. df['time'] consist of a column of timestamps

```
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# i.e. x is a timestamp such as 1641772800 (or in date 2022-01-10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a whole `Timestamp` column to an array of `datetime.datetime` objects like this:

```
dt_array = df['dates'].dt.to_pydatetime()
# dt_array is an array of datetime.datetime objects
```

BUT as soon as you try to use that array to create/overwrite a pandas column it will end up as a `dtype='datetime64[ns]')`. For instance, columns `A` and `B` below will be `dtype='datetime64[ns]')`.

```
dt_array = df['dates'].dt.to_pydatetime()
# dt_array is an array of datetime.datetime objects
df['A'] = dt_array

# or in one line
df['B'] = df['dates'].dt.to_pydatetime()
```