# Adding holidays column to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe object `df` for the following dates:

```
>> df.index

DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04',
               '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08',
               '2015-01-09', '2015-01-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=10, freq=None)
```

I want to add a column to `df` showing whether or not it is a public holiday:

```
import pandas as pd
import holidays

df['hols'] = holidays.CountryHoliday('AUS',prov='NSW').get(df.index.to_datetime())
```

and get the error: `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'`.

If I try

```
df['hols'] = holidays.CountryHoliday('AUS',prov='NSW').get(pd.to_datetime(df.index))
```

I get error `TypeError: Cannot convert type '<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>' to date.`

I'm aware of the `workalendar` package from [Adding holidays columns in a Dataframe in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677112/adding-holidays-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-python), but I can't install the package on my university PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution using `lambda` function:

```
df['hols'] = pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda x: holidays.CountryHoliday('AUS',prov='NSW').get(x)).values
```

Method `get()` should receive only one value, not entire index or array.
Result when apply to Your data is:

```
                      hols
Date                      
2015-01-01  New Year's Day
2015-01-02            None
2015-01-03            None
2015-01-04            None
2015-01-05            None
2015-01-06            None
2015-01-07            None
2015-01-08            None
2015-01-09            None
2015-01-10            None
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice. Is there a way to convert 
the values into `1` (holiday) and `0` (no holiday)?

Comment: Yes, try: `df['hols'] = df['hols'].astype('bool').astype('int')`